# Передача объекта через DialogService в другую модель

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

(HospitalViewModel) По событию, через Command, срабатывает вызов нового окна

```
private void ExecuteDialog(object obj)
    {
        if (testViewModel == null)
            testViewModel = new TestViewModel(obj);

        var registerCommand = new UICommand()
        {
            Caption = "Register",
            IsCancel = false,
            IsDefault = true,
            Command = new DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs>(
                x => { }
            ),
        };

        var cancelCommand = new UICommand()
        {
            Id = MessageBoxResult.Cancel,
            Caption = "Cancel",
            IsCancel = true,
            IsDefault = false,
        };

        var result = DialogService.ShowDialog(
            dialogCommands: new List<UICommand>() {registerCommand, cancelCommand},
            title: "Registration Dialog",
            viewModel: testViewModel
        );

        if (result == registerCommand)
        {

        }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteDialog(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

(TestViewModel)в другой viewModel я получаю этот объект

```
public object Lpu { get; set; }
    public TestViewModel(object o)
    {
        Lpu = (TF_LPU1) o;
    }
```

(TestView)как во view получить этот объект?

```
 public TestView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

HospitalView.xaml

```
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dx:DialogService DialogWindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
        <dx:DialogService.ViewTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <view:TestView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </dx:DialogService.ViewTemplate>
        <dx:DialogService.DialogStyle>
            <Style TargetType="dx:DXDialogWindow">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="160"/>
                <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="ToolWindow"/>
            </Style>
        </dx:DialogService.DialogStyle>
    </dx:DialogService>
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>

<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lpu, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew">
        <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="MouseDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DialogCommand}">
                <dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
                    <dx:EventArgsToDataRowConverter/>
                </dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
            </dxmvvm:EventToCommand>
        </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False" NavigationStyle="Row">
                <dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItem GlyphSize="Large" 
                                       Content="Удалить МО" 
                                       Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Remove_32x32.png}"
                                       Command="{Binding Path=View.DataContext.RevomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Row}">
                    </dxb:BarButtonItem>
                    <dxb:BarItemSeparator />
                </dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Эту `TestViewModel` передать в `TestView` параметром конструктора (это касается кода на 3 картинке) и сделать присвоение дата-контексту переданного параметра, а не новой vm. Далее сделать `TF_LPU1` публичным свойством `public object TF_LPU1 { get; private set; }`, чтобы можно было получить объект.

Comment: либо передать этот объект вторым параметром во вьюшку. Мне кажется, что тут речь идет о том чтобы была одна и та же view-model.

Comment: Код приложите текстом, не картинками

Comment: @EvgeniyZ выложил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел решение

(HospitalViewModel)

```
private void ExecuteDialog(object obj)
    {

        var okCommand = new UICommand()
        {
            Caption = "OK",
            IsCancel = false,
            IsDefault = true,
            Command = new DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs>(
                x => { })
        };
        var cancelCommand = new UICommand()
        {
            Id = MessageResult.Cancel,
            Caption = "Cancel",
            IsCancel = true,
            IsDefault = false,
        };

        var result = DialogService.ShowDialog(
            dialogCommands: new List<UICommand>() { okCommand, cancelCommand },
            title: "Окно",
            documentType: "TestView",
            parameter: (TF_LPU1)obj,
            parentViewModel: this
        );


    }
```

Для передачи параметра нужно реализовать интерфейс ISupportParameter

```
public class TestViewModel  : ISupportParameter
{
    public virtual TF_LPU1 MyLpu { get; set; }

    object _Parameter { get; set; }

    object ISupportParameter.Parameter
    {
        get { return _Parameter; }
        set
        {
            _Parameter = value;
            MyLpu = (TF_LPU1) _Parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

потом, привязать в TestView

```
  DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource viewModel:TestViewModel}"
```

потом свободно обращаемся к полям объекта

```
<dxlc:LayoutControl>
    <dxlc:LayoutItem>
        <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=MyLpu.NameTiny}"/>
    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
</dxlc:LayoutControl>
```

Comment: Оставлю [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553) здесь, советую почитать и принять к сведению, тогда ваша задача будет решаться очень просто.

Comment: [принципы SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))