# Как правильно вывести коллекцию объектов в DataGrid? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется DataGrid с одной колонкой:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Height="390"
              Margin="10,10,9.8,20"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              ClipboardCopyMode="None"
              Grid.Column="1"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="197" 
                                Header="Коды" 
                                IsReadOnly="True" 
                                CanUserReorder="False" 
                                CanUserResize="False" 
                                CanUserSort="False" 
                                x:Name="codeColumn">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Имеется класс, отвечающий за хранение нужных мне данных в нужном мне формате:

```
public class Code
{
    public Code(string input)
    {
        SetValues(input);
    }

    private void SetValues(string input)
    {
        string[] splittedInput = input.Split('-');

        First = splittedInput[0].ToCharArray();

        Second = splittedInput[1].ToCharArray();

        Third = splittedInput[2].ToCharArray();

        Fourth = splittedInput[3].ToCharArray();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{new string(First)}-{new string(Second)}-{new string(Third)}-{new string(Fourth)}";
    }

    private char[] First { get; set; } = null;
    private char[] Second { get; set; } = null;
    private char[] Third { get; set; } = null;
    private char[] Fourth { get; set; } = null;
```

Сама коллекция и методы работы с ней описаны в отдельном классе:

```
internal class CodeCollection
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Code> Codes { get; private set; }

    public static void AddCode(Code newCode)
    {
        if (Codes == null)
        {
            Codes = new ObservableCollection<Code>();
        }

        Codes.Add(newCode);
    }

    public static void RemoveCode(int index)
    {
        if (Codes == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Codes.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

Привязки я попробовал выставить в конструкторе окна, метод добавления в коллекцию вызывается обработчиком события:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = CodeCollection.Codes;

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = CodeCollection.Codes;

        _ = inputTextBox.Focus();
    }

    private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.AddCode(new Code(inputTextBox.Text));
    }
}
```

Коллекция заполняется нужными мне данными, но проблема в том, что DataGrid ничего не выводит. Как мне нужно указать источник данных для DataGrid, чтоб он мог выводить их в описанную колонку?

Comment: Во первых, зачем вам ` = null;`, если по умолчанию эти объекты и так null? Во вторых, научитесь работать без использования имени контрола, не обращайтесь к нему напрямую! Создайте класс, в котором будет находится свойство коллекции, установите его как `DataContext` текущего окна/объекта и в XAML у нужного контрола задавайте ItemsSource. В 3-х. Если переопределяете `ToString`, то вам не нужно свойство, которое вернет строку! Сам WPF при привязке все переводит в строку сам.

Comment: Свойство, возвращающее строку, было создано в попытках привязать его к колонке строки (один из нагугленных вариантов решения проблемы, который тоже не сработал).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне не особо понятно по какому принципу задаётся значение в DataContext в XAML. Мне нужно указать там имя класса, в котором будет храниться коллекция?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586

Comment: Понятнее, честно говоря, не стало.

Я создал новый класс, в который перекинул свойство коллекции. Но я не понимаю что мне нужно сделать дальше. У главного (и единственного) окна задавать DataContext? Чем его задавать, свойством коллекции? В itemsSource у DataGrid тоже свойство коллекции передать? Если так, то вывод данных из коллекции в таблицу всё ещё не работает.

Comment: `DataContext` - это источник данных, где лежит все, что необходимо для окна. То есть задается объект, где будет ваша коллекция (прим: `DataContext = new MySuperClass();`). `ItemsSource` - тут уже задается контролу нужное публичное свойство, которое оно привяжет, также `ItemsSource` - это коллекция. Свойство должно быть в классе, которое установлено как `DataContext`. (прим. свойства: `public ObservableCollection<Code> Code { get; set;}`.

Comment: Теперь про столбцы (`DataGridTextColumn`), туда привязываются публичные свойства, которые находятся внутри класса, тип которого указан в коллекции. Привязка производится примерно так: `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}">`. Тут `Title` - публичное свойство, которое по должно быть в `Code`, ибо он указан как основной тип данных в коллекции (`ObservableCollection<Code>`).

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!

Применил изменения - всё заработало (за исключением того, что, судя по всему, при добавлении нового item в коллекцию, таблица генерит новые колонки). Плюс, пришлось убрать динамическую инициализацию коллекции - я только сейчас понял, что до этого передавал в `ItemsSource` `null`

Comment: `таблица генерит новые колонки` - если у вас стоит `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, то такого быть не может.

Comment: https://sun9-48.userapi.com/c855216/v855216005/12d405/DhipoHQI7NI.jpg - пустая таблица

https://sun9-11.userapi.com/c855216/v855216005/12d3fe/Ni7npJlYhEs.jpg - при добавлении элементов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Применил правки, предложенные в комментариях.

Итоговый вид XAML-кода `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Height="390"
          Margin="10,10,9.8,20"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          ClipboardCopyMode="None"
          Grid.Column="1"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="197" 
                            Header="Коды" 
                            IsReadOnly="True" 
                            CanUserReorder="False" 
                            CanUserResize="False" 
                            CanUserSort="False" 
                            x:Name="codeColumn"
                            Binding="{Binding Data}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Итоговый вид класса `Code`:

```
public class Code
{
    public Code(string input)
    {
        SetValues(input);
    }

    private void SetValues(string input)
    {
        string[] splittedInput = input.Split('-');

        First = splittedInput[0].ToCharArray();

        Second = splittedInput[1].ToCharArray();

        Third = splittedInput[2].ToCharArray();

        Fourth = splittedInput[3].ToCharArray();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{new string(First)}-{new string(Second)}-{new string(Third)}-{new string(Fourth)}";
    }

    public string Data => $"{new string(First)}-{new string(Second)}-{new string(Third)}-{new string(Fourth)}";

    private char[] First { get; set; } = null;
    private char[] Second { get; set; } = null;
    private char[] Third { get; set; } = null;
    private char[] Fourth { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Итоговый вид класса, хранящего коллекцию объектов для вывода в `DataGrid`:

```
internal class CodeCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<Code> Codes { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Code>();

    public void AddCode(Code newCode)
    {
        Codes.Add(newCode);
    }

    public void RemoveCode(int index)
    {
        Codes.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

Установка `DataContext` и `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, а также метод добавления нового элемента в коллекцию:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CodeCollection codeCollection = new CodeCollection();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = codeCollection;

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = codeCollection.Codes;
    }

    private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        codeCollection.AddCode(new Code(inputTextBox.Text));
    }
}
```

Comment: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = codeCollection.Codes;` - это лишнее, я вам уже говорил, что это должно устанавливаться в XAML (прим: `<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding Codes}"`). `public string Data =>` - это по сути тоже лишнее, вы переопределили `ToString()` у класса, а значит вам не нужно делать свойство, которое будет делать это еще раз. Попробуйте убрать у `DataGridTextColumn` `Binding`, либо сделайте что то вроде этого `Binding = "{Binding}"` или `Binding = "{Binding Path=.}"`.

Comment: `Data` используется как свойство для `DataGridTextColumn`.
Код в моём ответе - рабочий.