# Как связать List с ListView в XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как в Xaml, через DataContext или ItemSource(или я не правильно думаю, что бы прибиндить из XAML свою коллекцию _ListProduct. (Желательно с тремя столбиками, но то уже не столь важно.)

Из Кода делал вот так, но мне нужно из Xaml привязатся:

```
LBs.ItemsSource = ListProducts._ListProducts;
```

У меня есть класс Product

```
 public class Product
{
    private string name;
    private double cost;
    private double weight;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => name = value;
    }

    public double Cost
    {
        get => cost;
        set => cost = value;
    }

    public double Weight
    {
        get => weight;
        set => weight = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $@"{Name} {Cost} {Weight}";
    }
}
```

Есть класс ListProduct

```
 class ListProducts
{
    private static readonly List<Product> _products = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product{Name = "Banana", Cost = 10.55, Weight = 233.8},
        new Product{Name = "Potatos", Cost = 17.85, Weight = 70.8},
        new Product{Name = "Qiwi", Cost = 19.30, Weight = 90.8},
    };

    public static List<Product> _ListProducts
    {
        get => _products;
    }
}
```

Я Пробовал вот так:

```
<Window x:Class="ListProduct.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListProduct"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="LBs" Width="300" Height="450"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Почему вы все время ставите MVVM, если им тут даже и не пахнет? Также, почему у вас все статичное? Ну и `Я Пробовал вот так` - и каков результат?

Comment: понял mvvm уберу.

Comment: А вот по поводу статичное или не статичное, какая разница, вообще не относиться к моему вопросу, вопрос как прибиндить, а не стоит ли мне писать static.

Comment: Я к вам с каким то негативом пришел сюда? Вроде нет, по этому и вы свой держите при себе. Если спрашивают, то наверно надо знать, верно? Если ваш вопрос про то, как в XAML указывать привязки, то `<ListView ItemsSource = "{Binding _ListProducts}"`, где `_ListProducts` - публичное свойство в классе, который установлен, как `DataContext` (как его установить, советую почитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)). Я не уверен, что привяжет нормально к статике. И тут опять возвращаемся к вопросу, почему статик? Ибо WPF с ним ох как нехотя дружит...

Comment: Смотрите, потом попадетесь на грабли из за вашего статика. Рекомендую его использовать как можно меньше. Я лично использую его только в каких то утилитах, расширениях, не более. В общем удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так получилось реализовать

```
<Window x:Class="ListProduct.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListProduct"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ListProducts/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
        <ListView 
        x:Name="listView" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="401" 
        Margin="10,10,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="773"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding _ListProducts}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tag="Cost" Click="ButtonSort_OnClick">Название</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Cost}" >
                    <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tag="Cost" Click="ButtonSort_OnClick" >Цена</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Weight}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tag="Weight" Click="ButtonSort_OnClick">Вес</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```