# Отображение IconSource ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Подскажите почему нет отображения в ListView, место под картинку есть, а самой картинки нет или я не правильно пытаюсь прибиндить?

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewClassWork.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewClassWork"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>

    <ListView x:Name="listView1">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="YellowGreen" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="100" Header="Mark">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Img}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="32" Height="32"></Image>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Mark}"></Label>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Model}">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly string[] Marks = {"Opel", "Daewoo", "Mercedess", "BMV", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Tesla"};
    private readonly string[] Model = {"AB", "XT", "LX", "GT", "RS", "VZ", "XS"};

    readonly Random rand = new Random();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (var i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        {
            var sMark = Marks[rand.Next(0, Marks.Length)];
            var sModel = Model[rand.Next(0, Model.Length)];
            var sYear = rand.Next(1972, 2019);

            var numberIcon = rand.Next(0, 3);

            BitmapImage img;

            switch (numberIcon)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"myResources/test.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"myResources/test2.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"myResources/test3.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                }
            }

            var auto = new Car(sMark,sModel,sYear, img);
            this.listView1.Items.Add(auto);
        }

    }
}


public class Car
{
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Img { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
    }
    public Car(string mark, string model, int year, BitmapImage img)
    {
        Mark = mark;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;
        Img = img;
    }

}
```

Comment: Биндите вы явно не так. А точней у вас нет как таковых привязок. Тут `this.listView1.Items.Add(auto);` вы добавляете в компонент новый Item, не привязываете. Вам стоит задать где то `DataContext`, который будет указывать на класс, где вы будете хранить коллекцию ваших авто. В самом XAML вы задаете `ItemsSource = "{Binding Коллекция авто из DataContext}"` и вот только тогда у вас можно будет сказать, что привязка есть. Что касательно отображения картинки, то у вас мне кажется, неверно заданы пути, если я не ошибаюсь, они задаются как `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/путь до картинки.png")`.

Comment: Да, именно так и задаю, только вот как связать с помощью DataContext чуть не понял

Comment: Я не вижу что бы вы "Так" задавали в коде выше, я вижу `new Uri(@"myResources/test2.jpg", UriKind.Relative)`. Про [DataContext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562578/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-mvvm-app-xaml-cs-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Comment: new Uri("pack://application:,,,/путь до картинки.png") - но у меня то находиться картинка в myResource.resx

Comment: Я вам дал направление, думаю найти то правильный путь можно и самим) Я с ресурсами уже очень давно не работал, помню что от туда они вовсе брались вроде как таким способом: `Properties.Resources.Файл`. В общем попробуйте вашу `img` просто задать какой то обычной картинке, без привязки. Появится - я не прав, а если нет, то ищите как правильно брать путь из ресурсов.

Comment: понял, спасибо, буду пробовать