# Как можно следить за фокусировкой на элементе?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть ListBox, и я хочу следить за фокусировкой на его элементах. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы срабатывала команда при фокусировки на одном из его элементов и срабатывала команда при расфокусировки. Это нужно подружить с MVVM. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как бы вы поступили

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не гарантирую строгий стиль MVVM, но это может работать :)

Обязательно скачать из **NuGet**: `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`

Что бы работало: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Если нужны будут дополнительные комментарии, напиши, я добавлю комментарии в коде, что бы понятнее было.

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:ViewModel></viewmodel:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>



    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="26,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Забит Магомедшарипов"></ListBoxItem>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FocusEpta}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NetFocusaEpta}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        </ListBox>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="348,221,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DelegateCommands FocusEpta
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommands((x => { Test1(); })); }
        }

        public DelegateCommands NetFocusaEpta
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommands(x => { Test2(); }); }
        }


        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public void Test1()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Фокус Есть");
        }

        public void Test2()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Фокус пропал");
        }
    }
```

DelegateCommands:

```
private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public DelegateCommands(Action<object> _execute, Func<object, bool> _canExecute = null)
        {
            this._execute = _execute;
            this._canExecute = _canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this._canExecute == null || this._canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this._execute(parameter);
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за доходчивый код, вопросов нет

Comment: Не за что, удачи :)

Comment: Я вам советую прочитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562578/), также пару замечаний: 1. Не двигайте контролы в студии руками, пишите XAML код сами, ибо потом вы из за подобного `Margin="348,221,0,0"` будете страдать... 2. `MessageBox` для отладки использовать не хорошо, советую вам отказаться от подобного, да и вроде это является нарушением MVVM. 3. Вы в культурном обществе, вроде не гопник или быдло, так к чему эти "Епта"? Лично мне подобное как то противно читать. Ну и 4. Зачем вы реализуете `INotifyPropertyChanged`, если в коде он не используется?

Comment: 1. Это я знаю, но для быстрого примера это критично? Я думаю нет. 2. Это для явного примера, если человек будет использовать код, иначе если я ему накидаю пару Label, человек может просто не понять, я же не знаю, насколько он опытен. 3. Не по делу. 4. CTRL+C - CTRL+V. Быстро код, Made China.

Comment: 1-2,4. Если человек изучает только основы, то он как губка, будет впитывать все, даже ошибочное.  И вот посмотрит человек например, ага `MessageBox` в коде используется, значит это не нарушение, о, а `DataContext` в XAML прямо задают, так можно было? И он узнав это от вас, начнет использовать это везде дальше. Вы здесь в роли учителя, а значит учите правильному! 3. Не относится к вопросу, да, но относится к вашему ответу. Я ставлю вам за это минус, исправите - уберу. Мое негативное отношение к подобному я вам выразил.

Comment: Зануда - это про Вас.
Человеку помогло? 
Если ему нужно, он пойдет чекать YouTube, а там каждый 2-ой показывает свой крутой MVVM с прелестями. 
Если он захочет изучить строгий стиль MVVM - он изучит. Я тут не в роли учителя. Человек задал вопрос, я поделился знаниями.