# Смена картинки при нажатии кнопки. Кнопок много

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-commands

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать большое количество кнопок с одинаковыми двумя изменяющимися картинками так, чтобы не писать для каждой кнопки свойство и команду(автоматизация, так сказать).И желательно, чтоб соблюдался MVVM.

Пример кода

Разметка XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstImage}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Resources/image1.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstImage}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Resources/image2.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border>
        <Canvas>
            <Button x:Name="button1" Width="41" Height="38" Opacity="1" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="146">
                <Image x:Name="Qwe1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="button2" Width="41" Height="38" Opacity="1" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="146">
                <Image x:Name="Qwe2" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="button3" Width="41" Height="38" Opacity="1" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="146">
                <Image x:Name="Qwe3" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
            </Button>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

И моя VM:

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isFirstImage;
        public bool IsFirstImage
        {
            get { return isFirstImage; }
            set { isFirstImage = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsFirstImage"); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        private RelayCommand toggleCommand;
        public RelayCommand ToggleCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return toggleCommand ??
                  (toggleCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                  {
                      IsFirstImage = !IsFirstImage;
                  }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот у меня три кнопки, все три кнопки изначально при запуске приложения имеют image1, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на определенную кнопку менялась картинка этой же кнопки, на которую нажал (в данный момент у меня при нажатии на любую кнопку меняются картинки на всех кнопках одновременно, оно и понятно, ведь биндинг к одному и тому же свойству). Подскажите, как написать грамотней код, чтобы к каждой кнопке не прописывать отдельное свойство и отдельную команду. Ведь будет неудобно писать для 100 кнопок 100 свойств, 100 команд и 100 привязок в разметке.

Comment: Во первых [откажитесь от VM в View слое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562578). Во вторых, опишите вашу задачу подробнее, что должно меняться я лично так и не понял. Ну и в третьих, подумайте логически сами, если у вас кнопок N количество, то это уже массив, верно? Что отображает массив в XAML? `ItemsControl` и все его производные. Значит что вам надо сделать? Правильно, завести коллекцию VM, которую вы через `ItemsControl` выводите, переопределив там нужный вид элемента и привязав его к нужным свойствам.

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, можно Вас попросить на основе моего отредактированного кода сделать маленький пример с ItemsControl, о котором Вы написали, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Если элементов много, то это коллекция/массив.
- Если коллекция изменяется (удаляются/добавляются элементы), то это `BindingList` или `ObservableCollection`, ибо они имеют реализацию `INotifyCollectionChanged`.
- Если коллекция статична, то можно использовать хоть массив.

Исходя из этого вы можете сделать следующее:

1. Создаем коллекцию:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Items { get; }
   ```

   `ViewModel` - это ваш класс со свойствами для кнопки.
   `get;` - нам по сути надо получить только из нее элементы, не инициализируя ее постоянно, по этому тут нет `set;`.
2. Инициализируем коллекцию и заполняем.

   ```
   public MainViewModel()
   {
       Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>
       {
           new ViewModel() //Задаем нужные свойства если надо.
       };
   }
   ```

   Вы в любой момент можете написать `Items.Add(...)`.
3. Переделываем XAML:

   Меняем

   ```
   <Canvas>
       <Button x:Name="button1" Width="41" Height="38" Opacity="1" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="146">
           <Image x:Name="Qwe1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
       </Button>
       <Button x:Name="button2" Width="41" Height="38" Opacity="1" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="146">
           <Image x:Name="Qwe2" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
       </Button>
       <Button x:Name="button3" Width="41" Height="38" Opacity="1" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="146">
           <Image x:Name="Qwe3" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
       </Button>
   </Canvas>
   ```

   На

   ```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Button Width="41" Height="38" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}">
                   <Image Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}" Width="41" Height="37"/>
               </Button>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

   Тут как видите все лишнее убрано, используется `ItemsControl`, который привязан к коллекции `Items`. В качестве `ItemsPanel` задан `WrapPanel` (тут смотрите сами, как кнопки будут размещаться). Также переопределен шаблон `ItemTemplate`, в него переехала ваша кнопка.

Вот собственно и все, у вас должно будет вывести всю коллекцию `Items` с заданным шаблоном.

---

<sup>P.S. Код писал на коленке, так что могут быть неточности.</sup>