# Обращение к элементам XAML вне класса MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Я использую MVVM. Есть элемент XAML со своим `Name="nameElement"`. Я могу обращаться к нему только из класса MainWindow, но мне не хотелось бы писать лишний код в этом классе.

Например: есть ListBox с `Name="kernelList"`

View:

```
<ListBox x:Name="kernelsList" SelectionChanged="kernelsList_SelectionChanged" Margin="160,0,41,10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <CheckBox Margin="5" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisualization}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Я могу обращаться к *"kernelList"* **только** в классе MainWindow. Допустим хочу добавить item в список

```
kernelsList.ItemsSource = Kernels;
```

Как можно обращаться к элементам XAML из других классов?

Comment: Если вы используете mvvm, то вам не надо обращаться к xaml напрямую. Используйте vm и привязки

Comment: На мой взгляд вы выбрали не самый удачный тип сценария при написании приложения, но коли вы уже забрели в эти тернии, то нужно помогать выйти из ситуации. Поясните пожалуйста, при каких событиях будет добавляться элемент (например на 2 форме мы нажимаем кнопку, или на другой форме изменяется какая то величина)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).` + нужный элемент.

А вообще пишите код так, как вам выгодно. Не всё можно реализовать привязками, не всегда они будут работать. Главное - рабочий код, а не красивый или правильный.

Comment: Мне интересно, а что нельзя сделать на привязках? Да и заявление, что "главное рабочий код" - это бред, ибо по вашему всякие паттерны проектирования придумали лишь для красоты?

Comment: Много чего нельзя сделать на привязках. А многое что можно сделать, делается через лишний неудобный избыточный код. Нравится ходить окольными путями - ходите). Вы, видимо, из тех, кому нужны рюшечки, а не результат.

Comment: Это не ответ. Я может чего не знаю, вот хотел бы узнать у вас - Чего "многое" нельзя сделать на привязках? Хоть один пример дайте незнающему человеку.

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть ряд нарушений MVVM из за которых вы сейчас страдаете.

1. По правилам MVVM вы не должны знать о том, что у вас в View слое, как и View слой не должен знать нечего про реализацию. Обратившись по имени вы нарушили это правило, ибо у вас есть строгая связь с объектом. Удалите XAML и запустите проект, если у вас реализован верно MVVM, то он запустится, код отработает.
2. У вас как я понял нет базового класса, который задан как `DataContext` и из за этого вы не понимаете как действовать дальше. Сделайте один класс, назовите его например `MainViewModel` и сделайте там свойство другой ViewModel, вот уже у вас связь.

Исходя из всего этого давайте сделаем простой проект, который будет реализовать правильный MVVM подход:

1. Создаем для удобства директорию `ViewModels` и в ней делаем основной класс, который назовем стандартно, `MainViewModel`.
2. Задаем `DataContect` окну на созданный нами класс. Будем делать [правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553):

   - Заходим в `App.xaml` и удаляем там строку `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`.
   - Далее заходим в `App.xaml.cs` и переопределяем там `Startup`, в котором мы создаем объект окна, задав ему `DataContext`.

     ```
     protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
     {
         base.OnStartup(e);
         new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }.Show();
     }
     ```
3. На данном этапе у нас имеется окно, которое имеет источник данных в виде `MainViewModel` класса из которого оно с радостью возьмет все привязки. Давайте создадим там свойство и убедимся в этом:

   - Напишем в `MainViewModel` простое свойство со стандартным текстом (помним, что привязка доступна **только к публичным свойствам**!)

     ```
     public string Text { get; set; } = "Тестовое значение";
     ```
   - В XAML окна сделаем `TextBlock`, который будет брать текст из этого значения:

     ```
     <TextBlock
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="30"
         Text="{Binding Text}" />
     ```

   Результат

   [image: Result1]

Как видим все успешно привязалось и View слой нечего не знает про ViewModel слой.

4. Сделаем теперь другую ViewModel, которая будет иметь доступ к основной, иметь свои свойства для привязки и будет менять значение текста, который мы привязали выше.

   - Делаем новый класс, название берем любое, которое вам нравиться. Я назову `SecondViewModel`. Помним, что у нас есть для этого специальная папка, стоит наверно создать в ней?
   - Передача значений в C#, это DI (если интересно, может погуглить что это) и два основных способа передачи являются через конструктор или через свойство. Если объект зависим от другого, то эту зависимость лучше передать через конструктор. Наша же VM зависима будет от главной, так давайте сделаем передачу через констуруктор:

     ```
     class SecondViewModel
     {
         private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

         public SecondViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
             => this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
     }
     ```

   Теперь этот класс невозможно создать без `MainViewModel`, а через приватное поле (которое можно сделать публичным свойством для привязки) мы имеет доступ ко всем отдаваемым `MainViewModel` объектам.

   - Давайте теперь сделаем тестовое поле для привязки и привяжем его:

     - Само свойство в `SecondViewModel`:

       ```
       public string TestValue { get; set; } = "Значение из SecondViewModel";
       ```
     - Инициализация `SecondViewModel` в главной VM. Простое публичное свойство, которое в конструкторе класса инициализируется:

       ```
       public MainViewModel()
       {
           SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel(this);
       }

       public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; }
       ```
     - Ну и в XAML просто используем его там, где нам надо:

       ```
       <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
           <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Text}" />
           <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding SecondViewModel.TestValue}" />
       </StackPanel>
       ```

Результат вывода свойств из разных VM:

[image: Result2]

Осталось последнее - изменить главной VM из `SecondViewModel`. Тут я думаю вы уже догадались, что мы уже имеем ссылку и без труда через нее можем обратиться к нужному свойству, например давайте это сделаем через конструктор:

```
    public SecondViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        this.mainViewModel.Text = "Измененное значение из SecondVM";
    }
```

И в итоге мы получим измененное значение:

[image: Result3]

Тут есть один подводный камень - Если у вас свойство меняется во время работы приложения, то интерфейс надо оповестить об этом через `INotifyPropertyChanged`, иначе в интерфейсе будет старое значение!

Answer (score 0):

В Form1 создаем новое окно и передаем в него ссылку на нужный объект

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 w1 = new Window1();
        w1.LB = this.kernelsList; // передаем ссылку на ListBox в форму Form2
        w1.Show();
    }
```

В Form2 объявляем объект, которому присвоена ссылка и изменяем его, тем самым внося изменения в нужный элемент

```
    public ListBox LB;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LB.Items.Add("SomeThink"); //можете проводить любые манипуляции теперь
    }
```

P.S. вот вы и обратились к элементу XAML из другого класса.
С уважением и удачи.

Comment: Вы знаете что такое MVVM? Если да, то к чему этот ответ нелепый?