# Как в рамках MVVM добавить элементы на View?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я пишу WPF приложение, используя паттерн MVVM.

Есть контейнер в XAML(*StackPanel*), я должен по нажатию кнопки добавлять в него элементы: *StackPanel*ы, и в каждом *Button*, *TextBlock* и *CheckBox*.

Я решил для этого использовать DataTemplate, погуглив, самое понятное, что я нашёл для себя этот пример: [metanit.com](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.3.php) Насколько я знаю, в MVVM паттерне нельзя чтобы View знала о ViewModel или Model. Так вот в этом примере напрямую обращаются(MainWindow.cs) к списку из View `phonesList.ItemsSource = Phones;`.

Как правильно решить мою проблему, стоит для этого использовать DataTemplate или есть другое(более правильное) решение? Как в рамках MVVM добавить элементы на View, не обращаясь к ним напрямую?

Comment: Если брать тот код, что на метаните, то уберите все `Path=` (бессмысленны они), дальше замените `phonesList.ItemsSource = Phones;` на `DataContext = this;` (но это [не правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), создайте лучше отдельный класс, куда вынесите все данные и в App классе задавайте `DataContext`). Ну и последнее, что остается, это заменить `x:Name="phonesList"` на `ItemsSource = "{Binding Phones}"`. Все, у вас почти чистый MVVM, остается убрать событие, привязав выделенный элемент к своему свойству (ибо использовать так события - нарушение MVVM).

Comment: Ваш комментарий я бы отметил как ответ!

Comment: Вы можете сами написать ответ, указав там то, что у вас получилось, я не против. А так, подобных ответов на SO полно, думаю можно было бы найти дубликат.