# Работа с CheckBox у элемента ListBox. ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть ListBox c `ObservableCollection<Model> Models`. В ListBox есть CheckBox, у которого привязка `IsVisualizationModel`

**View:**

```
<Window.Resources>
     <local:Model x:Key="models"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Models}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource models}, Path=IsVisualizationModel}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Model:**

```
 public class Model : INotifypropertyChanged
 {
    private bool isVisualizationModel;
    public bool IsVisualizationModel
    {
        get { return isVisualizationModel; }
        set
        {
            isVisualizationModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 
// interface implementation
 }
```

Проблема в том, что Model у меня целый список и далее в коде я его перебираю, проверяя свойство IsVisualizationModel. При проверке всегда получаю false, хотя привязка срабатывает и устанавливает свойство в true. Видимо привязка изменяет свойство не текущего элемента списка(ObservableCollection Models). Наверное, стоит как-то использовать ICommand, чтобы передать конкретный экземпляр списка и у него изменить свойство IsVisualizationModel. Я не знаю как это правильно реализовать. 
К тому же у меня тут никак не задействована ViewModel, что мне  тоже кажется не правильным.

Comment: `...у меня целый список и далее в коде я его перебираю...` подумайте над созданием общего массива для бэк-полей у свойств, например вместо `get { return isVisualizationModel; }` использовать `get { return visualsArray[3]; }`

Comment: @Bulson здесь всё, к сожалению, проще :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перемудрили.

Вот просто вот так должно заработать

```csharp
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisualizationModel}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

**Ошибки**

Вот этот xaml:

```xaml
<local:Model x:Key="models"/>
```

логически эквивалент этого C#:

```csharp
dictionary.Add("model", new Model());
```

то есть, вы создаете один экземпляр класса `Model` и кладете его в словарь ресурсов. Зачем? Уберите это совсем.

К тому же, как @EvgeniyZ верно подметил в комментариях:

> Задавать в XAML источник данных вообще является нарушением MVVM и [вот почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562578/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-mvvm-app-xaml-cs-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/562586#562586).

`Source={StaticResource models}` указывает на что что надо прибиндить каждый чекбокс из `ListBox` в общему свойству, которое находится в единственном экземпляре класса `Model`, хранимом в словаре ресурсов окна. В этом случае должно работать так, что при изменении любого из чекбоксов, изменяются все одновременно.

Другими словами, ничего нового писать не нужно, а просто убрать изобретение.

Почему это рабоотает:

```xaml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisualizationModel}"/>
```

А потому что `ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"` задает `DataContext` каждому элементу списка `ListBox`, указывающий на элемент привязанной коллекции.

То есть `DataContext` здесь `{Binding Models}` и здесь `{Binding IsVisualizationModel}` - два разных контекста. Первый - это экземпляр класса `MainViewModel` второй - текущий элемент в коллекции `Models` типа `ObservableCollection<Model>`.

И почему кстати класс назвали `Model`? Если отталкиваться от его функции, я бы его назвал `ListBoxItemViewModel`.

Comment: У класса другое название, я изменил для примера. Огромное Вас спасибо, второй раз выручаете!

Comment: @AlanAugust не за что, только запомните, что этот трюк с `DataContext` элементов коллекции работает у всех контролов с `ItemsSource` одинаково. Без этого знания будет трудно понять, как работают привязки к коллекциям во **View**.

Comment: Задавать в XAML источник данных вообще является нарушением MVVM и [вот почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ верно, я поясню только что имеется в виду вот это `<local:Model x:Key="models"/>`, а не `Source={StaticResource models}`. Менять источник данных для `Binding` не является нарушением MVVM, а когда это `RelativeSource`, то вообще считается обычным делом.