# Почему не отображаются данные отдельном окне?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Пытаюсь отобразить данные не в главном окне, но не могу понять, почему они не отображаются. Есть класс:

```
public class StudentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public StudentModel(int remoteId, int receiverId)
   {
            RemoteId = (ushort)remoteId;
            ReceiverId = receiverId;
   }
   public StudentModel()
   {

   }

   public List<string> textString { get; set; } = new List<string>();

   protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public void QuestionsAdd(string text)
   {
            Questions.Add($"{Questions.Count + 1}. " + $" {text}");
   }
}
```

В другом классе я добавляю в коллекцию объекты:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<StudentModel> Students { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<StudentModel>();

        IFileService _fileService;

        IDialogService _dialogService;

        private readonly DeviceManager deviceManager = new DeviceManager(new VotumDevicesManager());

        public MainWindowViewModel() { }
        public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogService dialogService, IFileService fileService)
        {
            _dialogService = dialogService;
            _fileService = fileService;

            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                Students.Add(new StudentModel());
            }

            deviceManager.votumManager.ButtonClicked += VotumManager_ButtonClicked;
        }

private void GettingAQuestionsRemotely(int RemoteId, ButtonClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsT2TextPresent && e.Button.Type == ButtonType.PauseT2)
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    //**Добавляем в коллекцию объекты**
                    Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RemoteId.Equals(Convert.ToUInt16(RemoteId)))?.QuestionsAdd(e.T2Text);
                    var std = Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RemoteId.Equals(Convert.ToUInt16(RemoteId)));
                    if (std != null)
                    {
                        std.Question = e.T2Text;
                        OnTick -= std.UpTime;
                    }
                }));
            }
        }

public RelayCommand<StudentModel> questionCmd = null;
        public RelayCommand<StudentModel> QuestionCmd => questionCmd ?? (questionCmd = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
        {
            new QuestionView().ShowDialog();
        },
            (param) =>
            {
                return (param != null && param.Questions.Count == 0) ? false : true;
            }
            ));
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Guess.Yourself.QuestionView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Guess.Yourself"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Архив вопросов" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Topmost="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:StudentModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lv" Background="Gray" Height="300" MaxHeight="300" MinWidth="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Потому что вы создаете новый экземпляр прямо в разметке. Это неправильно. Убирайте `Window.DataContext` из разметки

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хорошо, а как тогда корректно сделать? В ListView так же не правильно же...

Comment: Нет, новый экземпляр не должен тут создаваться вообще, кто-то должен установить готовый экземпляр извне

Comment: [Точка входа в MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)

Comment: @АндрейNOP В классе MainWindowViewModel я создаю объект класса StudentModel и там же в методе GettingAQuestionsRemotely добавляю текст лист.

Comment: Хорошо, а как вы устанавливаете DataContext вашему окну QuestionView?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Получается, что никак. В этом и загвоздка. Раньше я просто передавал в команде список объектов через параметр команды, в code-behinde QuestionView устанавливал ItemSource получая список через конструктор. Так работало, но если в главном окне менялась размерность списка, то при скролле списка объектов в окне QuestionView ловил эксепшн об изменении списка в другом окне.

Comment: А как вы окно создаете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не совсем понял вопроса. Если Вы про вторичное окно, то самым обычным образом public QuestionView() => InitializeComponent(); Точно так же и первое создаю.

Comment: Кто и где дергает этот конструктор? Почему этот кто-то не устанавливает окну нужный DataContext?

Comment: @АндрейNOP У главного окна DataContext - DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(new DefaultDialogService(), new TextFileService()); У второго окна контекста на данный момент нет, конструктор дёргается в одном месте, в классе MainWindowViewModel в команде открытия окна new QuestionView().ShowDialog();

Comment: Ну вот здесь значит и надо установить DataContext: `new QuestionView { DataContext = ... }.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Другой вопрос — на сколько это правильно, VM по хорошему не должна зависеть от View, на перспективу вам добавить прослойку, которая будет создавать нужную View по запросу от VM

Comment: @Андрей NOP Действительно получилось!) Спасибо!) Оформите ответ, пусть Вам зачтётся!)

Comment: Напишите самостоятельно, у меня нет желания. Да и никакие дополнительные очки мне уже не нужны :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем и целом дело заключалось в том, что не нужно было DataContext устанавливать в XAML, а установить в коде там, где окно создаётся:

```
public RelayCommand<StudentModel> QuestionCmd => questionCmd ?? (questionCmd = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
        {
            new QuestionView() { DataContext = param }.ShowDialog();
        },
            (param) =>
            {
                return (param != null && param.Questions.Count == 0) ? false : true;
            }
            ));
```