# Вопрос по wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хочу добавлять в лист сразу псевдоформу, пример на картинке, соответственно чтобы с ней можно было работать, взаимодействовать с кнопками, предоставляется ли это возможным? Вернее не так, иожно ли создать такой объект (псевдоформу), чтобы потом, просто создавая экземпляр данной формы добавлять его к пример в listView. [image: состоящую из текстовой ячейки и двух кнопок]

Comment: Научитесь делать привязки, у вас не должно быть никаких "псевдоформ" в коде, а просто класс, содержащий в себе нужные данные, а уже XAML определяет дизайн для нужного класса.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `DataTemplate` в `ListBox`:

```xml
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ваш тип для предмета">
            <!--ваша XAML разметка для каждого элемента-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Для отображения уникальных данных (отн. каждого элемента) можно использовать привязки:

```xml
...
<ListBox ItemSource="..." SelectedItem="..." SelectedItemIndex="...">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Item">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

…где `ItemsSource` имеет значение след. типа:

```cs
ObservableCollection<Item>
```

…где `Item` – это:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

В WPF нет ограничений на содержимое контролов – всё, что можно отобразить; т. е. вы можете запихнуть туда `Grid`, а в него уже ваш `text` с `b1` и `b2`.

---

Подробнее о `ItemTemplate` и `DataTemplate` можно узнать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.3.php).

---

Сейчас все нормальные [обычные] приложения WPF используют паттерн [MVVM](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php). По ссылке прочитаете всю инфу, вот реализация:

<sub>MainViewModel.cs</sub>

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Item? selItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public Item? SelectedItem // вообще нужно через `SelectedItemIndex`, но тоже работает
    {
        get => selItem;
        set
        {
            selItem = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        SelectedItem = null; // нет выделения // убрать: строчка чисто для разяснения
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, propertyNa,e);
}
```

<sub>MainWindow.xaml.cs</sub>

```cs
MainViewModel vm;

public MainWindow()
{
    vm = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

<sub>MainWindow.xaml</sub>

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Item">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Привязка – это просто копирование или создание ссылки на другие определённые данные. Значение привязывается ещё до отрисовки и обработки ввода (и даже раньше событий загрузки) ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?view=netcore-3.1)).

Comment: По поводу ответа есть пару замечаний: 1. `Для отображения уникальных данных` - как ваш пример даст разный вид отображения для разных объектов в коллекции? Чтобы было разное отображение, надо установить дополнительно `DateType` у `DataTemplate` и делать их несколько, с разным дизайном под каждый тип. Это я думаю стоит уточнить, что бы у человека не было вопросов. 2. Наверно стоит показать как привязать коллекцию, я на 100% уверен, что автор вопроса совершенно не знает как работает WPF и если он изначально увидит "эталонный" вариант, то дальше будет действовать по нему.

Comment: `DataContect` в XAML, это [нарушение MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), раз уж решили по правилам MVVM (что я не просил), то тогда наверно стоит делать это правильно, или сделать пометку почему так не стоит делать.