# Как привязать Binding к полям класса, точнее объекта? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

У меня есть обычный класс с полем public string name {get; set;}
Как вывести в < Label Text="{}" > значение этого поля для нужного объекта.

Comment: `с полем public string name {get; set;}` - это не поле. `Как вывести` - задаете `DataContext` (или что там у вас в Xamarin), ну и привязываете `<Lable Text = {Binding name} />` (имена могут чуть отличаться, но суть такая же). Так что, лично мне, ваш вопрос не ясен.

Comment: BindingContext в Xamarin. Так в том то и дело я не знаю что написать в Bindingcontext

Comment: Тот класс, в котором у вас данные, это свойство, указанное в вопросе. Если говорить человеческим языком, то вы должны сказать языку по типу: "Ей, в этом классе ты должен брать все данные для привязки!", он вам, "Ок, теперь, когда ты будешь писать `{Binding свойство}`, я его возьму из указанного тобою класса.".

Comment: <Label Text="{Binding name}" BindingContext="{Binding classname}"/>

Так?

Comment: Нет, `DataContext` задается окну целиком, а не определенному элементу. Я не знаю как там в Xamarin, в WPF было бы [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562578/220553). Пока можете просто в конструкторе окна указать источник

Comment: спс. в xamarin в stacklayout нельзя указать bangingcontext. Буду искать информацию за бугром:)