# C#. Добавление нового пункта в ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

Пишу окно истории проектов (что-то типа Visual Studio). Приведённый здесь код, при добавлении каждого нового пункта списка, правит данные сразу у всех пунктов, делая их одинаковыми. Никак не могу исправить данный код, чтобы при добавлении нового пункта, он имел свои данные (отличные от других пунктов). Я ещё не волшебник, а только учусь, поэтому прошу помощи у сообщества!

XAML-код:

```
// шаблон пункта списка

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" Margin="30,0,0,0"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                <!-- строку полного пути в 'Tag' нового пункта -->
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding fullFileNameProject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>

                <!-- Содержимое пункта (иконка и две строки) -->
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!-- иконка логотип -->
                                <Image x:Name="logoName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Margin="0,9,0,0" Source="{Binding logoProject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>

                                <!-- имя файла -->
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Margin="2,3,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Text="{Binding fileProject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>

                                <!-- строка пути папки -->
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="12"
                                    Margin="2,0,0,9" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Text="{Binding folderProject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

C#-код:

```
// иконка пункта
private string _logoProj;
public string logoProject {
    private set {
        _logoProj = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("logoProject");
    }
    get { return _logoProj; }
}

// имя файла
private string _fileProj;
public string fileProject {
    private set {
        _fileProj = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("fileProject");
    }
    get { return _fileProj; }
}

// путь папки
private string _folderProj;
public string folderProject {
    private set {
        _folderProj = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("folderProject");
    }
    get { return _folderProj; }
}

// строка "путь папки + имя файла"
private string _fullfnameProj;
public string fullFileNameProject {
    private set {
        _fullfnameProj = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("fullFileNameProject");
    }
    get { return _fullfnameProj; }
}


// INotifyPropertyChanged
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {

    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

C#-код (добавить новый пункт):

```
// счётчик
public int cnt = 0;

    // Добавить новый пункт в список

    // иконка пункта
    logoProject = @"/Resource/iar24.png";

    // строка имени файла
    fileProject = "ide" + String.Format("{0}.iprj", ++cnt);

    // строка папки
    folderProject = @"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Projects_wpf\ide" + String.Format("{0}", cnt);

    // строка полного пути файла
    fullFileNameProject = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderProject, fileProject);

    // создать пункт
    var item = new ListBoxItem();

    // добавить пункт в список
    listBox.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Сделайте привязку, а не работайте напрямую с контролом, а данные разбейте на классы, которые будут находиться в привязанной коллекции.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте поговорим про то, какие вы допустили здесь ошибки:

1. Вы данные привязываете к одним и тем же свойствам. Представьте, что у вас есть некая банка, в которой лежат бумажные листочки, а также, за пределами банки, есть еще один листок с текстом. И вот вы сейчас для чего-то ищете тот листок, что за банкой, а не пишете на каждом листочке по отдельности.
   Другими словами, здесь:

   ```
    {Binding logoProject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}
   ```

   И в других подобных местах, у вас идет поиск предка (вы ищете окно), в котором вы и берете свойство для привязки. А раз свойство у вас используется везде одно и тоже, то и данные везде будут одинаковые.
   Решением этого будет сделать все как положено, привязать все к коллекции, которая будет содержать класс с нужными свойствами и вот тогда свойства будут искаться, как и положено, "внутри банки".
2. Вы используете контрол `ListBox` как место хранения данных и это плохо, ибо не его ответственность, он служит лишь для того, чтоб данные отобразить, а уже какие данные, это дело вашего кода, отдельных классов и коллекций. В WPF принято использовать привязки, а отличным набором правил для этого существует MVVM подход, по которому приложение разбивается на 3 слоя (Model - источник данных; View - UI и все то, что общается с пользователем; ViewModel - некий связующий слой, который берет из M слоя нужные данные, подготавливает свойства для привязки, ну и обрабатывает то, что произошло в V слое) и вот попробуйте двигаться в этом направление, ибо WPF без MVVM это не просто...
3. `<ListBox.Resources>` - Если используете ресурсы, то лучше выносите их отдельно, в словарь ресурсов, это и удобно и практично. Если же вам надо единожды изменить вид у одного контрола, то делайте все через его свойства:

   ```
   <ListBox>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
       ....
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```
4. Вы, мне кажется, не совсем понимаете, что такое `INotifyPropertyChanged` - Задайте себе вопрос: будет ли меняться свойство после запуска приложения через код (не UI)? Если ответ "ДА", то вам нужно вызывать INPC, если же "НЕТ", то он там лишний. Если вы хотите получить данные от пользователя (от UI), а не выдать данные пользователю, то тоже INPC вам не нужен, ибо интерфейс обновляет свойство, а вот свойство интерфейс нет.
   В вашем случае различные пути до проектов, они ведь статичны, не обновляются по мере работы приложения, ну так зачем им INPC? Также не пишите его во всех классах, сделайте один базовый класс реализации INPC и от него наследуйтесь, этого достаточно.
5. Наименования - в C# есть принятые [правила наименования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), по которым, публичные данные пишуться в CamelCase стиле, то есть, каждое слово с большой буквы, без пробелов. Это конечно все рекомендации, но большинство людей им следуют и приятней видеть код, который написан по этим правилам.
6. Интерполяция строк - в C# уже мало кто пишет так: `"ide" + String.Format("{0}.iprj", ++cnt)`, ибо с 6-й версии языка была добавлена такая вещь, как интерполяция строк, которая позволяет делать так: `$"ide{++cnt}.iprj"`.

И так, исходя из всего этого, давайте перепишем ваш код:

- `DataContext` - нам нужен источник данных, некий класс, который будет содержать в себе все для привязок. Я рекомендую вам [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553) ответ, который подскажет как следует поступить и как его устанавливать, в нашем примере источником данным пусть будет само окно, а значит в его конструкторе я напишу:

  ```
  DataContext = this;
  ```

  Теперь все публичные свойства, что будут в классе `MainWindow` будут доступны для привязок.
- Класс одного проекта (пункта, как вы их называете) - нам нужен класс, который содержит в себе все необходимые свойства одного (как я понял у вас список проектов) проекта. Делаем, к примеру следующее:

  ```
  public class Project
  {
      public string Icon { get; set; }
      public string File { get; set; }
      public string Path { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  Как видите, я не пишу повторно `Project`, ибо сам класс подразумевает, что это свойства одного проекта. Также стоит учесть тот факт, что иконка, например, не должна быть случайно затронута в процессе разработки кем-либо и для этого стоит такие свойства делать приватными для записи (`private set;`) или вовсе только для чтения (`{get;}`).
- Коллекция проектов - теперь нам нужно публичное свойство с коллекцией, которая будет содержать в себе ранее созданный класс. В WPF для коллекции подойти может много чего, но стоит задаться вопросом: будут ли меняться (добавляться/удаляться) данные в этой коллекции? Если ответ "ДА", то надо использовать те, что реализуют `INotifyCollectionChanged`, ибо мы не увидим новых объектов в UI. К таким коллекция относятся минимум 2: `BindingList<>` и `ObservableCollection<>`. Если ответ "НЕТ", то можете использовать что угодно, хоть простой массив. Я выберу `ObservableCollection<>`:

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
  ```
- Добавление объектов - теперь вместо `listBox.Items.Add(item);` вы должны делать `Projects.Add(item);`, тем самым вы можете уже заметить то, что мы не обращаемся к UI, он нам не интересен, работа идет лишь с данными.
- XAML - Убираем в нем все `x:Name`, переносем из ресурсов стиль, убираем поиск предка у привязок, ну и устанавливаем `ItemsSource`, указав там коллекцию.

  ```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" Margin="30,0,0,0"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- иконка логотип -->
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Margin="0,9,0,0" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>

                    <!-- имя файла -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Margin="2,3,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Text="{Binding File}"/>

                    <!-- строка пути папки -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12"
                                    Margin="2,0,0,9" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Text="{Binding Path}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  ```

Вот, собственно, и все. Постарался для вас объяснить все как можно более подробнее, надеюсь направил на верный путь. Удачи в изучении!

Comment: Евгений большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Попробывал ваши поправки - всё работает как надо. Но возникла одна проблема. У объекта "ListBoxItem" есть свойство "IsSelected". По этому свойству я раньше находил выделенный пункт в списке. Теперь список состоит из объектов "Project", где нет свойства "IsSelected". Пробывал класс "Project" наследовать от "ListBoxItem" - не работает. Можно ли каким-либо образом определить текущий выделенный пункт в списке? Мне необходим такой доступ, ведь по клику на пункте, я далее буду использовать строку пути из этого пункта.

Comment: @vas31 `"Project" наследовать от "ListBoxItem"` - забудьте вы про это, я вас учу наоборот как можно сильнее уйти от контролов, а вы опять лезете в них... Представьте себе, что у вас нету UI, вообще, есть просто коллекция и разные методы, все, вот с этим и работайте. По поводу взять выделенный объект: У `ListBox` есть `SelectedItem`, привяжите его к заранее созданному свойству (например `public Project SelectedItem {get;set;}` и в XAML: `<ListBox SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedItem}" ...>`, все, при выделение у вас будет в свойсте то, что выбрали и всего при помощи одного свойства)

Comment: Я нашёл такой способ узнать выделенный пункт:  var selItem = listBox.SelectedItem as Project;

Comment: @vas31 вы меня не слушаете, ну чтож, дело ваше, делаете как считаете нужным...

Comment: Я конечно попробую по вашему варианту. Просто надо перестроить мышление на новый лад (wpf) и думаю придётся потыкаться несколько раз лбом в стену, прежде чем поменяется мышление и выработается правильное "направление". Спасибо за ваше терпение!