# Не понимаю связи между View и ViewModel. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В окне 2 элемента: TextBox - в который вводится текст, и Label - в который этот текст передается. При запуске программы Label считывает дефолтные данные из TextBox, но если впоследствии менять текст, то в Label измененный текст не отображается.

```
<Window x:Class="Example_INotifyPropertyChenged.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example_INotifyPropertyChenged.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="c0"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="c1"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="r0"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="r1" ></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxtText" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TextBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    <Label x:Name="label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Mode=Default, Path=LabelContent}"></Label>

</Grid>
```

и сама ViewModal

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Example_INotifyPropertyChenged.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
    private string _textBoxText="textBox";
    public string TextBoxText
    {
        get => _textBoxText;
        set
        {
            if(_textBoxText!=value)
            _textBoxText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(LabelContent);
        }
    }        
    public string LabelContent { get => TextBoxText;}
}
```

}

Comment: Что вы видите тут? `OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)`, а что вы видите здесь `OnPropertyChanged(LabelContent);`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понял вопрос. А что я должен был там увидеть?

Comment: Наверно то, что для INPС требуется `PropertyName`, а вы пихаете значение свойства `LableContent`, которое у вас `textBox`. Чтоб этот пример заработал, достаточно `OnPropertyChanged(LabelContent);` заменить на `OnPropertyChanged("LabelContent");`.

Comment: Евгений, еще раз извиняюсь, но можете привести пример кода, т.к. я не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду. Взяв в кавычки имя свойства, проблема не решилась.
p.s. мне искренне интересно как еще можно решить данную проблему, тк приведенный пример, это просто пример, чтобы разобраться в некоторых тонкостях...Ниже я привел пример своего решения.

Comment: Ну как так не решилась, вот ваш [код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sopyQ.png), где я только взял в кавычки  `LabelContent`, вот [XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjAfI.png), он как видите без каких-либо изменений. Ну и [все работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtUj4.gif). Понимайте метод `OnPropertyChanged()` как "ей, интерфейс, тут свойство (имя) изменило значение, подтяни новые данные!" оно не обновляет все другие свойства, оно лишь обновляет то, что ему укажут. В вашем случае, вы пишете `OnPropertyChanged("textBox")`, где свойства `textBox` соответственно нету и обновлять нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что свойство TextBoxTex тоже нужно было извещать о том, что оно изменилось:

```
            set
        {
            if(_textBoxText!=value)
            _textBoxText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();//извещение всех кто привязан к этому свойству о том, что оно изменилось...
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBlogText));//извещение всех кто привязан к свойству LabelContent о том, что оно  изменилось
        }
```

Comment: Вообще у вас весьма странно тут все реализовано. 1. Зачем вам тут 2-е свойство, которое дублирует первое? Почему нельзя привязаться сразу к одному свойству? 2.  `if(_textBoxText!=value)` - лучше перенести в `OnPropertyChanged()` метод. 3. Сам INPC лучше вынести в отдельный класс. 4. Названия... `TextBoxText`, `x:Name="textBoxtText"`. 5. Зачем в XAML у вас везде `x:Name`? 6. `DataContext` в XAML [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562578/220553).

Comment: `//извещение всех кто привязан к этому свойству` - нет, это аналог `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxText));`, только `nameof(TextBoxText)` за вас пишет компилятор из-за атрибута `[CallerMemberName]`. Соответственно и `/извещение всех кто привязан к свойству LabelContent` тоже мимо.

Comment: Переписал код, сведя все к одному свойству, спасибо за рекомендации. 
Первичная реализация была аналогична примеру из "учебника".
Про имена элементов, тоже уже прочитал. 
А вот про DataContext в xaml пока не понятно, почему это плохо?

Comment: Я ведь дал ссылку, где все описано, не? MVVM, это подход, где все разбивается на мало связанных друг с другом слои, особенно UI (View) слой должен быть полностью отделен от кода. И вот теперь представьте, UI вдруг создает сам себе VM слой, содержит его, отвечает за его жизненный цикл и вовсе жить не может без своей VM. Нарушение-ли это? Определенно да. Также чтоб использовать основную VM где-либо еще, вам надо будет обратиться к окну, взять его `DataContext` и только тогда использовать VM, где надо и тут опять приходим к проблеме, где мы строго завязаны на UI и постоянно обращаемся к ней.