# Как поместить главное окно программы в папку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пробовал перемещать окно\удалять и потом (создавать окно в папке)

Но и то и другое вызывает исключение.
Как и где исправить это исключение ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А поменять стартовую точку? Подсказка `App`. Вообще стартовую точку лучше [переписывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). Ну и, если вы перемещаете так окно, то не забывайте менять ему и Namespace.

Comment: Откройте App.xaml, там найдете StartupUri. Путь надо поменять, если вы переместили главное окно.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Подсказки App было достаточно )

Comment: А такой вот вопрос, стоит ли прятать файл App.config в отдельную папку?  Или лучше этого не делать?

Comment: @Кирилл: Нет, не стоит, система будет искать его именно в каталоге программы.