# Помогите разобраться с потоками WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Выношу загрузку информации в другие потоки через Task.Run и столкнулся с проблемой.

Этот код работает:

```
Task.Run(()=> News.Load().ContinueWith(news =>
        {
            foreach (NewsObject n in news.Result)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    Home_NewsListView.Items.Add(new TextBlock().Text = n.Title);
                });
            }
        }));
```

`News.Load()` это `async Task`

Но если я хочу загрузить изображение в `Image`, то появляется исключение `Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.`:

```
Task.Run(()=> UserProfile.loaduseravatar(User).ContinueWith(avatar =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (avatar.Result != null)
                {
                    User_avatar.Source = avatar.Result; //Тут вылезает исключение
                }
            });
        }));
```

`UserProfile.loaduseravatar(User)` это `async Task`

```
public static async Task <BitmapImage> loaduseravatar(UserInfo User)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(User.AvatarURL);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Методы показывайте целиком, где это происходит. А лучше вообще весь класс. Вы перепутали асинхронное и многопоточное программирование, и чтобы это исправить, надо вообще понять, что происходит.

Comment: Оу, работа с контролами в код-бихайнде - это удел очень суровых разработчиков. Давайте весь код-бихайнд и xaml разметку, попробуем привести в порядок. Если кратко, то WPF очень сильно отличается от винформ, подходом к разработке, но вы как-то смогли этот момент упустить и поехали напролом...и приехали. :)

Comment: 1. Используйте привязки, это основа основ WPF! 2. Зачем вам тут загрузка аватарки? Почему нельзя сразу ее отобразить? 3. Почему вы используете `async/await` так... топорно? Где вообще ключевые слова `async` и `await`? Почему `.Result;`? 4. `static`... Серьезно?

Comment: Метод `loaduseravatar` внезапно не является асинхронным, он синхронный.

Comment: @aepot в общем я намудрил знатно. Как понял проще всего это сделать через XAML: `<Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding Uri}"/>` и подгружать туда изображение через cs:`var vm = (VM)DataContext;
vm.Uri = User.AvatarURL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделал так:

XAML:

```
Image x:Name="avatar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="2.5,0,0,0" Width="64" Source="{Binding AvatarUri, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
class VMData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string avataruri;
        public string AvatarUri
        {
            get => avataruri;
            set
            {
                avataruri = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AvatarUri)));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }


public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new VMData();
            logincomplete();
        }
private void logincomplete()
            {
                var vm = (VMDataContext)DataContext;
                vm.AvatarUri = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/616c357f3f6fe7d3bc84bd495b43d93c";
            }
```

Comment: Поздравляю вас с озарением! Только зачем `var vm = (VMDataContext)DataContext;`? Сделайте приватное поле/свойство за конструктором, да его и используйте дальше где хотите. Также, если хотите всеж MVVM подход, то убирайте все `x:Name`, забудьте про них, только если в стилях, либо внутри XAML логика. INPC вынесите в отдельный класс, от которого наследуйтесь (и найдите более удобную реализацию его). Ну и также, советую глянуть [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). А, ну и на последок - имена, помните про то, как именуются все объекты в C# `logincomplete` -> `LoginComplete`.