# Использование UserControl с DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, usercontrol

Всем добрый день! Появилась следующая проблема, необходимо создать MenuControl, состоящий из XAML-разметки (стандартной)

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlsLibrary.Views.MenuControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ControlsLibrary.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MenuControlViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid/>

</UserControl>
```

, MenuControl.cs (стандартный)

```
    public partial class MenuControl : UserControl
    {
        public MenuControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

и MenuControlViewModel.cs (пустой класс)

```
    public class MenuControlViewModel
    {
        public MenuControlViewModel(IMediator m)
        {}
    }
```

, при этом MenuControlViewModel должен быть задан как DataContext. Так же MenuControlViewModel должен иметь конструктор, принимающий экземпляр интерфейса IMediator в качестве параметра. Передачу в конструктор параметра сделал с помощью DependencyInjection:

```
private readonly IHost _host;

        public Register()
        {
            _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IMediator, Mediator>();
                }).Build();
        }

        public void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            using var serviceScope = _host.Services.CreateScope();
            var window = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
            window.Show();
        }
```

Во всём остальном коде DI работает.
Но есть проблема: т.к. MenuControlViewModel должен быть DataContext, то нужно его где-то задать. Если задавать в XAML – будет ошибка, т.к. нельзя передать ничего в качестве параметра. Если задавать в MenuControl.cs, то нужно передать параметры в MenuControl.cs, Но будет ошибка – UserControl запускается только со стандартным конструктором, без параметров.

Comment: `при этом MenuControlViewModel должен быть задан как DataContext` - не должен, это [нарушение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553) MVVM, а также вообще проектирования в целом, ведь контролы должны быть универсальны и самостоятельны, а не зависеть от некого `MenuControlViewModel`. Вот задайте себе вопрос - простой `TextBox` просит от вас создание дополнительного класса для работы? Нет, он имеет органы управления (`Text` например), через который он и понимает, что выводить. А у вас, что будет если удалить этот класс? Запустится ли проект? Нет...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, то же самое можно сказать и про окна и страницы. Они не просят создания дополнительного класса для работы, но при этом если удалить класс окна или страницы, то проект тоже не запустится.

Comment: Вы меня наверно не поняли. Ок, перефразирую... Все цвета, шрифты, анимации и др. - это View слой, этот слой не должен быть зависим от данных. Сами же данные, это Model слой (база, сайт, устройство, файлы и др.). Ну а связующий слой, тот, который берет из Model и предоставляет доступ для View - это ViewModel. Другими словами, тот же `TextBox`, у вас не должно быть, что внутри у него прописан свой `DataContext` из которого он читает текст, нет, он должен быть самостоятельны, со своим дизайном и дизайн-логикой, а данные, он берет из вне через привязку (`<TextBox Text = "{Binding SomeText}">`)

Comment: Вы же сейчас делаете так, что он строго зависит от данных, от DataContect и прочего. Вот к примеру вам надо сделать тоже меню, но для других данных, у него будет другой VM класс (а-ля `CustomMenuViewModel`), что, будете делать еще один контрол, дублировать код, лишь чтоб изменить там данные? Ну согласитесь, что-то тут не то... Касательно окна - не путайте то, что вы задаете `DataContext` из вне (использование контрола) и то, что вы задаете его внутри (при реализации).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: А если по простому - работает "viemodel first", то есть вы что-то меняете во вьюмоделях, а view через систему биндингов реагирует на это - создает и уничтожает контролы. Касательно вашего меню - контрол должен получать DataContext извне - явно или нет (задается в верстке)