# Как использовать элемент Plot в OxyPlot для WPF?

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

Как я понял из документации, в `OxyPlot` реализовано два подхода к отображению графиков. С помощью `PlotView` и вынесения логики отображения в код. И с помощью `Plot` и `LineSeries`, ориентированных на XAML-разметку. Я пытаюсь действовать по этой инструкции:
https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/hello-wpf-xaml.html

Я скачал через NuGet пакет `OxyPlot.Wpf`. Подключил пространство имен `xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"`. Далее я пытаюсь вставить разметку из примера:

```
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"/>
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Однако сталкиваюсь с ошибкой XLS0414 ***«Не удалось найти тип "oxy:Plot". Убедитесь, что не пропущена ссылка на сборку и что все сборки, на которые заданы ссылки, выполнены»***

Отдельное непонимание у меня вызывает тот факт, что аналогичный кейс для фреймворка `AvaloniaUI` отлично работает. В этом случае я подключил пакет `OxyPlot.Avalonia` и пространство имен `xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/avalonia"`. Элемент `Plot` доступен.

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы использовать XAML-разметку для оформления графиков? Сама разметка очень простая и почти дословно повторяет пример из документации:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.WPF.ViewModels"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        Height="450" Width="800"
        Title="{Binding Path=Title}">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <oxy:Plot Title="{Binding Title}">
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
</Window
```

Как я пришел к проблеме (не имеет прямого отношения к вопросу):

> Мои коллеги в контексте некоторой работы создают относительно простые приложения с использованием WinForm и Teechart, основное назначение которых - показать данные из БД и в некоторых случаях отобразить график. Но на горизонте замаячило требование сделать подобное под Linux. Я проявил некоторую инициативу, решив заранее разобраться в кроссплатформенной разработке. Моё внимание привлек фреймворк `AvaloniaUI`. Однако, мне не удалось использовать в нем Teechart. Недолгий поиск альтернатив привел к `OxyPlot`. Я предположил, что будет неплохой идеей реализовать однотипный учебный проект одновременно и на `AvaloniaUI` и на `WPF`, чтобы не столкнуться с глюками Open Source фреймворка. Однако, столкнулся с непонятным поведением в WPF.

Comment: `Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы использовать XAML-разметку для оформления графиков?` - не верить слепо ошибкам, а попробовать пересобрать проект? XAML штука капризная, она часто не сразу воспринимает добавленные для нее компоненты, очистка и пересборка почти всегда в этом помогает. Если нет, то у вас есть еще ошибка, помимо этой. `<Window.DataContext>` кстати [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553).

Comment: К сожалению, проект уже был многократно пересобран... Спасибо за замечание о DataContext.

Comment: Ну, тогда у вас либо есть еще ошибка, либо документация устарела (судя по [примерам](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/WPF/SimpleDemo/MainWindow.xaml#L12) так оно и есть, ибо используется везде `PlotView`).