# datagrid внутри datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Идея такая. У меня есть производство, в datagrid вывожу данные с базы. Во время этого производства были простои. Внутри datagrid производства пытаюсь реализовать datagrid простоев связанных с производством. Путём нажатия на строку datagrid, получить данные из этой строки и с помощью entity framework отправить запрос в базу и выдать простои(в данный момент у меня просто SQL запросы). В идеале конечно сразу получить простои которые относятся к производству.
Это мой код оформленный в UserControl

```
    <DataGrid materialDesign:ScrollBarAssist.ButtonsVisibility="Visible" materialDesign:ScrollBarAssist.ThumbCornerRadius="10" 
IsReadOnly="True" 
x:Name="References" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EnableListBox}" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
FontSize="{DynamicResource GlobalFontSize}"
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"
MinWidth="900">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Date"
                        MaxWidth="110"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Part"
                        MaxWidth="260"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding Part}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Start"
                        MaxWidth="93"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding Start}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="End"
                        MaxWidth="93"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding End}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Прод. мин"
                        MaxWidth="110"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding ProdLength , StringFormat={}{0} Мин}"/>
    
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="SPH"
                        MaxWidth="75"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding SPH}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Defect Ratio"
                        MaxWidth="115"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding DefRatio, StringFormat={}{0} %}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Net Util Rate"
                        MaxWidth="120"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding NetUtilRate, StringFormat={}{0} %}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="OEE"
                        MaxWidth="115"
                        Width="*" 
                        Binding="{Binding OEE, StringFormat={}{0} %}"/>
    
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
    
                                    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Downtimes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="grid1">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date1}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part" Binding="{Binding Part}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Respons" Binding="{Binding Respons}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ReasonComent" Binding="{Binding ReasonComent}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason" Binding="{Binding Reason}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Equipment" Binding="{Binding Equipment}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Side" Binding="{Binding Side}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CommentMNTC" Binding="{Binding CommentMNTC}"/>
    
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        </DataGrid>
```

когда я выбираю дату на календаре загружается список Производств,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

внутри каждого Производства вложен датагрид с Простоями, но Простои выгружаются все по всем производствам. Как сделать, чтобы простои вложенные выгружались только если Part производства = Part простоя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже мой класс

```
namespace Press_Shop_NMGR.ViewModel {
    public class Productions {
        public string Zn {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Slivers {
            get; set;
        }
        public object Hosh {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object Scratch {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object Oil {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object Wave {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object Wrinkle {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object Material {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object HoshPQA {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object DefectPL {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object DefectDMTNC {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object SplitDMTNC {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public string SplitPQA {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public string ScrapPQA {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public string ScrapPL {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public string ScrapDMTNC {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public string ScrapNEPE {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object SingleDefect {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object MissedDefect {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailZn {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailSlivers {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailHosh {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailScratch {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailOil {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailWave {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailWrinkle {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailMaterial {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailHoshPQA {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailDefectPL {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailDefectDMTNC {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailSplitDMTNC {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailScrapDMTNC {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailScrapPL {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailSingleDefect {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object TrailMissedDefect {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public object Part {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object Start {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public string End {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public string Date {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object SPH {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object ProdLength {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object Plan {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object Fact {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object Ok {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object DefRatio {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public object NetUtilRate {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public string OEE {
            get; internal set;
        }
        public TimeSpan aTime {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
        public TimeSpan bTime {
            get;
            internal set;
        }

    }

    public class Downtimes {

        public string Date1 {
            get; set;
        }
        public string CommentProduction {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Respons {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Reason {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Part {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Equipment {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Side {
            get; set;
        }
        public string CommentMNTC {
            get; set;
        }
        public string ReasonComent {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Date2 {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Length {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Title {
            get;
            internal set;
        }
    }

}
```

ну и сам код

```
public partial class ProductionView : UserControl {

        public string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=PressShop.accdb"; // путь к базе данных

        public ProductionView () {

            InitializeComponent ();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Downtimes> Downtimes {
            get; set;
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Productions> Productions {
            get; set;
        }

        public async void DataChanged (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

            if ( Mouse.Captured is CalendarItem )
                Mouse.Capture (null);


            await Task.Delay (2000);
            if ( DateReport.SelectedDates.Count > 0 ) {

                var start = ( DateReport.SelectedDates.Min () ).ToString ("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " 07:25:00";
                var end = ( DateReport.SelectedDates.Max () ).ToString ("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " 16:00:00";

                var sql =
                    "SELECT ref_summary.ref_start, ref_summary.ref_end, " +
                    "parts.part, ref_summary.ref_plan, ref_summary.ref_actual, ref_summary.ref_ok, " +
                    "ref_zn, ref_trailzn, " +
                    "ref_slivers, ref_trailslivers, " +
                    "ref_hosh, ref_trailhosh, " +
                    "ref_scratch, ref_trailscratch, " +
                    "ref_def_from_oil, ref_trailfrom_oil, " +
                    "ref_wave, ref_trailwave, " +
                    "ref_wrinkle, ref_trailwrinkle, " +
                    "ref_def_material1, ref_trailmaterial1, " +
                    "ref_def1, ref_traildef1, " +
                    "ref_def2, ref_traildef2, " +
                    "ref_def3, ref_traildef3, " +
                    "ref_split, ref_trailsplit, " +
                    "ref_miss_grip, " +
                    "ref_def_material2, " +
                    "ref_def4, ref_traildef4, " +
                    "ref_def5, ref_traildef5, " +
                    "ref_def6, " +
                    "ref_single, ref_trailsingle, " +
                    "ref_missed, ref_trailmissed " +
                    "FROM ref_summary INNER JOIN parts ON ref_summary.ref_part = parts.id " +
                    "WHERE ref_start BETWEEN #" + start + "# AND #" + end + "# " +
                    "ORDER BY ref_summary.ref_start";

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection (connection);
                conn.Open ();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand ();
                command.CommandText = sql;
                command.Connection = conn;
                OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader ();

                if ( Productions == null )
                    Productions = new ObservableCollection<Productions> ();

                while ( read.Read () ) {
                    Productions.Add (new Productions {
                        Zn = read[6].ToString (),
                        Slivers = read[8].ToString (),
                        Hosh = read[10].ToString (),
                        Scratch = read[12].ToString (),
                        Oil = read[14].ToString (),
                        Wave = read[16].ToString (),
                        Wrinkle = read[18].ToString (),
                        Material = read[20].ToString (),
                        HoshPQA = read[22].ToString (),
                        DefectPL = read[24].ToString (),
                        DefectDMTNC = read[26].ToString (),
                        SplitDMTNC = read[28].ToString (),
                        SplitPQA = read[30].ToString (),
                        ScrapPQA = read[31].ToString (),
                        ScrapDMTNC = read[32].ToString (),
                        ScrapPL = read[34].ToString (),
                        ScrapNEPE = read[36].ToString (),
                        SingleDefect = read[37].ToString (),
                        MissedDefect = read[39].ToString (),

                        TrailZn = read[7],
                        TrailSlivers = read[9],
                        TrailHosh = read[11],
                        TrailScratch = read[13],
                        TrailOil = read[15],
                        TrailWave = read[17],
                        TrailWrinkle = read[19],
                        TrailMaterial = read[21],
                        TrailHoshPQA = read[23],
                        TrailDefectPL = read[25],
                        TrailDefectDMTNC = read[27],
                        TrailSplitDMTNC = read[29],
                        TrailScrapDMTNC = read[33],
                        TrailScrapPL = read[35],
                        TrailSingleDefect = read[38],
                        TrailMissedDefect = read[40],

                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime (read[0].ToString ()).ToShortDateString (),
                        Part = read[2].ToString (),
                        Start = Convert.ToDateTime (read[0].ToString ()).ToLongTimeString (),
                        End = Convert.ToDateTime (read[1].ToString ()).ToLongTimeString (),
                        aTime = TimeSpan.Parse (Convert.ToDateTime (read[0].ToString ()).ToLongTimeString ()),
                        bTime = TimeSpan.Parse (Convert.ToDateTime (read[1].ToString ()).ToLongTimeString ()),
                        ProdLength = ( ( TimeSpan.Parse (Convert.ToDateTime (read[1].ToString ()).ToLongTimeString ()) - TimeSpan.Parse (Convert.ToDateTime (read[0].ToString ()).ToLongTimeString ()) ).TotalSeconds ) / 60,
                        Plan = read[3].ToString (),
                        Fact = read[4].ToString (),
                        Ok = read[5].ToString (),
                        DefRatio = read[6].ToString (),
                        NetUtilRate = read[8].ToString (),
                        OEE = read[8].ToString (),
                        SPH = Convert.ToInt32 (read[6].ToString ()) * Convert.ToInt32 (read[12].ToString ()),
                    });

                    var Part = read[2].ToString ();
                    using ( var con = new OleDbConnection (connection) ) {

                        con.Open ();
                        Console.WriteLine ("select dt_date,dt_length,dt_comment,dt_response,dt_reason,dt_part,dt_equip,dt_side,dt_comment_mntc,dt_reason_break,dt_Edate,parts.part FROM downtime_summary INNER JOIN parts ON downtime_summary.dt_part = parts.id WHERE parts.part='" + Part + "' AND dt_date BETWEEN #" + start + "# AND #" + end + "# ");
                        using ( var sqlCom = new OleDbCommand ("select dt_date,dt_length,dt_comment,dt_response,dt_reason,dt_part,dt_equip,dt_side,dt_comment_mntc,dt_reason_break,dt_Edate,parts.part FROM downtime_summary INNER JOIN parts ON downtime_summary.dt_part = parts.id WHERE parts.part='" + Part + "' AND dt_date BETWEEN #" + start + "# AND #" + end + "# ", con) ) {
                            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery ();
                            var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter (sqlCom);
                            var dataSet = new DataSet ();
                            dataAdapter.Fill (dataSet, "downtime_summary");

                            if ( Downtimes == null )
                                Downtimes = new ObservableCollection<Downtimes> ();

                            foreach ( DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows ) {

                                Downtimes.Add (new Downtimes {
                                    Date1 = dr[0].ToString (),
                                    Length = dr[1].ToString (),
                                    CommentProduction = dr[2].ToString (),
                                    Respons = dr[3].ToString (),
                                    Reason = dr[4].ToString (),
                                    Part = dr[11].ToString (),
                                    Equipment = dr[6].ToString (),
                                    Side = dr[7].ToString (),
                                    CommentMNTC = dr[8].ToString (),
                                    ReasonComent = dr[9].ToString (),
                                    Date2 = dr[10].ToString ()
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                References.ItemsSource = Productions;
            }

        }
    }
```

понимаю что чтото забыл и не получается организовать биндинг главного дата грид, может кто подскажет

Comment: Где находится `DowntimesCollection`? Внутри того класса, который указан как `ItemsSource` для основного `DataGrid`? Не увидел, кстати, его указания в XAML, зато увидел `x:Name="References"`, что приводит к мысли, что вы используете контролы в коде, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: Да я сейчас переделываю эту часть кода где используются контролы. Сейчас не у компьютера, завтра буду продолжать. Может у вас есть на примете как правильно можно было бы организовать такой вывод данных. Я сколько гуглил, не нахожу подобного рода решения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ может мы сможем договориться с вами) чтобы быть полезными друг другу, я только учусь и готов вознаградить)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я покажу вам лишь простенький пример кода, где будет `DataGrid` внутри `DataGrid`, с привязками и всем остальным.

Смотрите, первым делом в WPF надо наладить систему привязок (`Binding`), это основа основ всего проекта, старайтесь не использовать в C# коде контролы через имена, не создавайте их там, не храните, ведь они для этого попросту не предназначены и вместо того, чтоб использовать один класс с несколькими свойствами, вы вечно дергаете элемент, который содержит в себе кучу лишнего (цвет, стиль, триггеры и пр.), что попросту будет лишним. Сразу вот разделите UI и данные на два лагеря, которые с собой почти не контактируют. Чтож, приступим...

1. **Зададим окну `DataContext`** - это некий источник данных, в котором UI и все его внутренние объекты будут искать свойства для привязки. По хорошему, это делать [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), но для простоты примера я весь код буду писать прям в классе окна (что не есть хорошо!!).

   ```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
   ```

   Тут как видите, задаем простому свойству значение, где `this` - это текущий класс (`MainWindow`).
2. **Данные** - нам нужны два класса, допустим пусть это будет "человек" и "задача человека", будем делать некий список дел.

   ```
   public record PersonTask(int Id, string Title, string Description);
   public record Person(int Id, string Name, int Age, IEnumerable<PersonTask> Tasks);
   ```

   `record` - это, по сути, тот же класс, только в неком сокращенном виде. Вам наверно надо будет сделать полноценные классы, с методами и прочим, в моем случае достаточно и этого.
3. **Свойства привязки** - в WPF привязка работает **только** к **публичным свойствам**, если у вас будет нечто другое, то попросту не увидите данные в UI, а в логе будет ошибка "не удалось найти публичное свойство". Следите за этим! Сейчас наша цель, это сделать свойство, которое будет содержать в себе список всех людей.

   ```
    public Person[] People { get; } = new Person[]
    {
        new(1, "Вася", 24, new PersonTask[]
        {
            new(11, "Помыть полы", "Очень грязные!"),
            new(12, "Перекусить", "Голоден..."),
        }),
        new(2,"Таня", 16, new PersonTask[]
        {
            new(21, "Цветы", "Полить, протереть, удобрить"),
            new(22, "Собака", "Погулять, покормить"),
        })
    };
   ```

   Как видите, тут простой массив, который сразу имеет в себе нужные данные. В вашем случае наверно эти данные будут поступать постепенно, а значит вам нужна будет коллекция, которая реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`, ведь именно эти интерфейсы (для свойств `INotifyPropertyChanged`) оповещают UI об изменениях данных. В C# уже есть коллекция, которая из коробки реализует данный интерфейс, звать ее `ObservableCollection<T>`, либо `BindingList<T>`. Так что, если у вас данные будут поступать в коллекцию **после** ее инициализации, то используйте одну из перечисленных выше коллекций, а не простой массив.
4. **Интерфейс** - в вашем XAML, по сути, все правильно, задаем `RowDetailsTemplate` в нужным видом. Получаем примерно следующее:

   ```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Возраст" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
   ```

Все, запускаем и смотрим:

[image: Result]
[image: Result open]

Вот данные у нас успешно и отобразились, со всеми привязками и другими наворотами.

Теперь давайте поговорим **почему не отображалось у вас**?
Код вы нам не показали, но предположу, что привязанное свойство `DowntimesCollection` было за пределами того класса, который указан в виде `ItemsSource` для главного `DataGrid`. Обратите внимание на мой пример, у меня класс человека содержит в себе свойство с задачами. В привязках WPF ведь как все работает: если вы внутри контрола разместили еще контрол, то источником данных для внутреннего контрола будет тот объект, что указан как источник данных для внешнего (это если коллекция).

**Как быть, если надо привязать внутренний `DataGrid` к списку за пределами внешнего?** - в таком случае надо перейти на уровень выше по привязками, найти "родителя" и у его `DataContext` забрать нужное нам свойство для привязки. В моем примере это примерно так:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tasks, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

То есть я задаю привязку к `DataContext.Tasks`, а также указывают `RelativeSource` в режиме `FindAncestor` (найти предка), с указанием типа "предка" `AncestorType=DataGrid`.

Comment: спасибо тебе! я всё не перестану удивляться доброте нашего народа! я реализовал то что хотел благодаря твоему решению)

Comment: я обновил вопрос, добавил код, подскажите пожалуйста где мои ошибки)

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин А как это относится к первоначальному вопросу? Вот вы добавили туда информацию, часть переделали, из-за чего мой ответ сейчас по сути стал бесполезным, не в тему, ведь суть вопроса другая. Так делать плохо... Ну а так, я бы сказал, что ваша проблема в самом коде, у вас все в одну кучу, вы не слушаете меня, вы дальше лепите свои костыли) Вот, к примеру я самым первым комментарием под вопросом написал `зато увидел x:Name="References"`, далее ответом показал, как надо. Почему у вас в коде по-прежнему `References.ItemsSource = Productions;`?

Comment: Также по коду еще кучу мест проблемных найти можно (например `Downtimes = new ObservableCollection<Downtimes> ();`, где `Downtimes` не реализует INPC, из за чего данные в коде UI не будут обновлятся.). Ну а так, если отвечать на "почему берет всех, а не только нужного" - наверно дело в запросе, в тех данных, что вы берете из базы? Смотрите что выдает строка `dataSet.Tables[0].Rows`.

Comment: ваш ответ по прежнему остался решением, просто я воспользовался лишь его частью, пробовал реализовать как у вас используя свои классы, и не получалось. В таблицу ничего не выводилось. Я понимаю что я тугой, потому что я учусь)
А по поводу References.ItemsSource = Productions; я правда не знаю как сделать по другому(
Во втором цикле где я вывожу запрос, он корректный, там меняется Part в запросе. Но коллекция общая получается в итоге а не к конкретной детали.

Comment: я вывел в консоль запрос sql а после dataSet.Tables[0].Rows и получаю, строку запроса с нужным Part а после System.Data.DataRowCollection ровно столько раз сколько простоев по данному Part. Тоесть всё верно получается, но на выходе я получаю общую коллекцию и делаю биндинг этой общей коллекции во вложенный датагрид. Напрашивается вывод, что нужно настроить биндинг главного датагрид, но я правда не догоняю как, сколько бы я не пересмотрел уроков и даже ваш пример подогнать не получилось. =(

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин `я правда не знаю как сделать по другому` - убрать эту строку и задать наверно привязку в XAML? `<DataGrid ... ItemsSource = "{Binding Productions}">`, все. Запомните просто раз и на всегда правило: в WPF все строится на привязках, у вас должно быть так, что вы в XAML полностью удаляете все, запускаете и ваша логика работает (без отображения естественно). То есть не должно быть каких либо `x:Name` и далее в коде `name.Property = ...`, нет, это грубое нарушение, особенно, если вы пишете по правилам MVVM (что по некоторым названиям вы пытаетесь сделать).

Comment: По поводу проблемы, я кажется понял в чем она у вас. Опять же, из за того, что у вас все в одну кучу, вы сейчас страдаете... У вас есть некое событие, по которому вы грузите **всю** базу сразу в память, когда должны загрузить **только** то, что сейчас отображается. Также и внутренний `DataGrid`, вы привязываете `SelectedItem` к некому свойству, в его `set` вызываете метод, который подгрузит новые данные в коллекцию, к которой в свою очередь и будет привязан внутренний `DataGrid`.

Comment: А по поводу "пробовал как у вас структуру, не получается" - плохо значит пробовали, не поняв суть. Вот представьте тело человека, у него есть внутри органы, сердце там, мозг, легкие и др. Вот тело - это один объект, оно отвечает только за свои функции (соединить все в одно целое и запустить), а каждый орган - это также отдельные объекты со своей логикой работы. Вот ваш код должен быть аналогичным этому примеру, где каждый класс, каждый метод, выполняет только **одну**, **свою** задачу. У вас вот сейчас в классе продуктов идет соединение с базой, оно за это должно отвечать? Нет. Так почему там?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132394/discussion-between---and-evgeniyz).