# Could not load file or assembly Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Tags: wpf

Кто-нибудь знает, как решить эту проблему?

```
    <Window.DataContext>
            <vm:MainViewModel/> <- ошибка из-за этой строки
    </Window.DataContext>
```

UPD: В общем, я решил эту проблему сам. Не знаю как это связано было, но в какой-то момент у меня констуктор перестал в принципе отображать все UserContol, но при запуске приложения они работали. В итоге, в самом конструкторе, в нижнем меню я поменял отображение элементов. До изменения у меня стояло "только элементы управления платформы". После внесения этих изменений у меня пропала эта ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ПКМ по проекту - очистить - пересобрать. И да, настоятельно [советую прочитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553).

Comment: ваш совет не помог

Comment: Ну, значит ваш namespace из XAML, что помечен как `vm`, отличается от того, что у класса `vm:MainViewModel`, либо у проекта есть помимо этого еще ошибка, которая мешает компиляции.