# реализация MVVM при работе с БД на C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ado.net, ssms

Как реализовать паттерн MVVM в WPF, используя модель данных Ado.NET?
У меня есть БД Northwind, модель которой я добавил в проект:
[image: Содержание проекта]
После создания модели данных обычно я заполняю класс Core следующим образом:

```
public static class Core
{
    public static NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
}
```

И использую на страницах что-то подобное:

```
public partial class CategoriesTablePage : Page
{
    public CategoriesTablePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AllCategories = Core.db.Categories.ToList();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Categories> AllCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Но из-за такого подхода в один момент на странице накапливается много ненужного кода, который не структурирован и все превращается в нечитаемую кашу. Как вы реализуете MVVM при работе с БД?

Comment: `public List<Categories> AllCategories { get; set; }` (ну и собственно заполнение листа) переместить во ViewModel, которая связана с View

Comment: ну и `DataContext` можно и лучше прописать в XAML

Comment: @Pekor `DataContext`, это [нарушение MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). А в вопросе он вообще непойми зачем указан...

Comment: Касательно вопроса - `static`, если вы такое пишете, то это сразу означает то, что вы делаете что-то не то. У вас должен быть класс, в котором должны быть прописаны все методы для взаимодействия с базой (например `List<Categories> AllCategories` - это Model слой, а вы пишете это в `Page`, что является `View` слоем. Ваш View слой не должен вообще знать что-либо о других слоях (как о Model, так и ViewModel). Поймите что такое слои в MVVM (`Model` - данные, `View` - вид приложения (UI), `ViewModel` - связующий слой, который делает свойства для привязки View и общается с Model), сейчас у вас каша.

Comment: Работа с внешним источником данных - это слой Model в MVVM, вся работа с базой должна быть внутри одного этого слоя. Всё, больше тут правил никаких нет.