# Не обновляется ListView при добавлении нового объекта в коллекцию

Tags: wpf, listview

Есть класс User и класс ViewModel с ObservableCollection. В ListView необходимо отобразить эту коллекцию, но, при добавлении новых объектов в коллекцию в ListView ничего не отображается. PropertyChange вроде реализовал, но не сильно понимаю, как он работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<User> _users;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users ?? (_users = new ObservableCollection<User>());
        }
        set
        {
            if (_users != value)
            {
                _users = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Users));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    }
}
public class User
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Department { get; set; }
    public User (string firstName, string lastName, string email, string userName, string password, int department)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;
        Department = department;


    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListView Name="UserList" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Margin="5"> 
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName }">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Text="User Name" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Text="First Name" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName }">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Text="Last Name" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email }">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Text="Email" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Department }">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="Deparment" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Ресурсы подгружены через XAML

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Добавление где? А так, почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553) - если у вас в коде есть `ViewModel vm = new(); vm.Users.Add(...);`, то поздравляю, у вас 2 экземпляра класса `ViewModel`, где UI привязан к одному, а данные вы меняете в другом.

Comment: Как вы и написали, у меня есть такое в коде
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       ViewModel Model = new ViewModel();

При нажатии на кнопку
 
 User user = new User(FirstNameTextBox.Text, LastNameTextBox.Text, EmailTextBox.Text, UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordBox.Password, DepartmentComboBox.SelectedIndex);
                Model.Users.Add(user);

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что в таком случае нужно изменить? Нужно сделать класс ViewModel абстрактным?

Comment: Я ведь дал вам ссылку на полноценный ответ почему так, как делаете вы - делать нельзя, там же и примеры того, как надо делать. Читайте внимательней.

Comment: Хочу сказать, вам, спасибо. Не сразу, но разобрался в своей ошибке. Теперь немного лучше разбираюсь в этой теме) Спасибо, что указали направление, где искать ответ)
P.s По вашему первому ответу понял, что у меня 2 класса, но не понимал, как это исправить