# Проблема с TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть один `TextBox` для ввода текста и дальнейшего его сжатия

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" AcceptsReturn="True"
                         SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="ru-ru"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=MainText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         FontSize="14" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
```

При попытке изменить содержимое через функции `Открыть` после которой ты выбираешь файл с текстом содержимое `TextBox` не меняется.

Вот само свойство

```
    private string _MainText = "empty";

    public string MainText
    {
        get => _MainText;
        set => Set(ref _MainText, value);
    }
```

Метод `Set` из класса`PropertyChangeding`

```
 public class PropertyChangeding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "") 
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));

    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T fules, T value, [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (object.Equals(fules, value)) return false;
        fules = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(prop);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Команда для открытия

```
 public ICommand OpenNewFileCommand { get; }

    private bool CanOpenNewFileCommandExecute(object p) => true;
    private void OnOpenNewFileCommandExecited(object p)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Text documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog.FilterIndex = 2;

        Nullable<bool> result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document
            string text = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
            MainText = text;
        }

    }
```

Весь XAML код

```
<Window x:Class="Course_work_IT.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Course_work_IT.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="900">

<Window.DataContext>
    <view:BaseVeiwModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="X" Command="{Binding CloseApplicationCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="Purple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="13" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Menu.DataContext>
            <view:PersonTextViewModel/>
        </Menu.DataContext>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Открыть" Command="{Binding Path=OpenNewFileCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding CloseApplicationCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Run" Command="{Binding Path=ChangeProgressBarCommand}"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="About">
            <MenuItem Header="Info"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=MainText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MainText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <MenuItem Header="Назад" Command="{Binding Path=ChangeSelectedItemCommand}" CommandParameter="-1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Вперед" Command="{Binding Path=ChangeSelectedItemCommand}" CommandParameter="+1"/>
    </Menu>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProcessProgressbar, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" MinHeight="15" MinWidth="50"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <ProgressBar Width="120" Height="14" Value="{Binding Path=ProgressBarValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode = OneWay}">
            </ProgressBar>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
    <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" FontFamily="Lucida Sans">

        <TabItem Header="Кодирование">
            
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                <Grid.DataContext>
                    <view:PersonTextViewModel/>
                </Grid.DataContext>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="381*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="259*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="56*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="104*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.825*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.175*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="{Binding Path=MainText}"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Алгоритм сжатия :"
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>

                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Margin="90, 0, 0, 0"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Algorithm}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_algorithms}"
                              Width="50">
                    </ComboBox>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <TextBlock 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Text="Название файла :"
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="10, 0, 20, 0"/>

                        <TextBox
                            Text="{Binding Path=FileName}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock
                        
                        Text="Степень сжатия :"
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>

                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Margin="110, 0, 0, 0"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Comprassion}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_comprassions}"
                              Width="100">
                    </ComboBox>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Content="Текст должен быть больше 200 символов" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=SaveNewFileCommand}" CommandParameter="true"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,0,0,13" 
                    Cursor="Hand" FontSize="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="сжать" FontSize="20" Margin="0,-4,0,0" FontFamily="Bodoni MT Black"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Декодирование">
            <Grid></Grid>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Если команда и свойство находятся в одном классе VM, то подозреваю, что используются разные экземпляры VM для DataContext. Покажите, каким образом устанавливаете DataContext для окна или UC...?

Comment: После некоторых тестов, а именно я создал в `Menu` поля, которые я забиндил к свойству MainText (то же свойство и у `Textbox`), эти поля взаимосвязанны и прекрасно текст в них меняется, но  в самом `TextBox`, почему то вначале текст привязывается, а после он не обновляется

Comment: `<Window.DataContext>` - [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), забудьте про это.  Это кстати наверно и ваша проблема с обновление, ибо у вас в XAML задан один экземпляр VM класса, а в коде небось пишете `var vm = new BaseVeiwModel();  vm.MainText = "....";`, что означает "Создать новый экземпляр класса и в нем поменять значение свойства". Другими словами, у вас **два** объекта `BaseVeiwModel` со своими значениями, где один привязан к UI, а другой используется в коде.