# Как обратиться к дочернему элементу xaml в C# коде

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю приложение для управления своей БД в WPF проекте.Хочу сделать вывод любой таблицы по нажатию RadioButton.У RadioButton дочерний элемент Label.В нем содержится название таблицы.Вот это название нужно вставлять вместо Table в функции(2 строки). Я знаю,что можно обращаться к кнопке через sender,но как обратиться к дочернему элементу кнопки не знаю.

Функция для вывода таблицы БД:

```
private void LibraryView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q; Initial Catalog=Library; Integrated Security=True");

            connection.Open();
            
            string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Table"; // Из какой таблицы нужен вывод 
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table"); // В скобках указываем название таблицы
            dataAdp.Fill(dt);
            StudentsGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; // Сам вывод 
            connection.Close();

        }
```

xaml код:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library"
        xmlns:SqlServer="clr-namespace:System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;assembly=EntityFramework.SqlServer" x:Class="Library.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="450" Width="800" ShowInTaskbar="False" Title="Library">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="StudentsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="333,133,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="LibraryObjects" Text="Список обьектов библиотеки"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfItem}" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" Height="31" >
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black" Checked="LibraryView">
                <Label>Libs</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Librarians</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Groups</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Faculties</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Students</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>SCards</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Teachers</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>TCards</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Departments</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Books</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Authors</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Categories</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Press</Label>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Background="#FF0025FA" Width="50" Height="50" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label>Theme</Label>
            </RadioButton>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="374,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Изменить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="518,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Удалить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="655,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Повторяющийся код - это всегда знак того что что-то пошло не так. Есть же списки и привязки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ужасный код, в котором вы смешали все возможное в одну здоровую кашу. Если учитесь, то учитесь правильным вещам сразу. В WPF используют привязки и XAML, это два основных и базовых механизма разработки любого проекта. Смысл их в том, чтобы в UI не было данных, а у вас как видите, данные являются частью UI, из-за чего вы и страдаете. Всегда задавайте вопрос "Что это?", "Должно это быть тут?", вот задаем эти вопросы для ваших `RadioButton`, получаем ответ "Нет, в UI нелогично иметь данные, которые потом потребуются в коде.", так почему они там?

Показываю самый простейший пример того, что у вас должно быть:

1. В конструкторе окна задаем `DataContext` на класс, где у нас будут все необходимые свойства для привязок (по хорошему это должно быть [за его пределами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)):

   ```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
   ```

   В данном случае тут `this`, что означает "Данные будут в классе окна" (что неправильно, лучше сделать отдельный класс!).
2. Создаем публичное свойство с нужным нам типом и нужными нам данными. В вашем случае это массив/коллекция строк:

   ```
    public List<string> Lables { get; } = new()
    {
        "Значение 1",
        "Значение 2",
        "Значение 3",
        "Значение 4",
        "Значение 5",
    };
   ```

   Если нужно добавить/удалить что-либо в коллекцию в ходе работы приложения, то нужна такая коллекция, которая реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`, в C# стандартно это `ObservableCollection<T>` или `BindingList<T>`. Без этого, при добавлении чего-либо в коллекцию, вы не увидите изменений в UI.
3. Данные наши готовы, осталось сделать для них вид, идем в XAML и пишем:

   ```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Lables}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
   ```

   Тут мы просто взяли нужных элемент, задали ему нужный вид и через `{Binding}` привязали к нужным свойствам, все, как видите ничего лишнего и данных наш UI не имеет вовсе. Не пойму, кстати, зачем тут `RadioButton`, но да ладно...

Как получить выбранное значение в C# коде, если мы не обращаемся по именам, а используем привязки? Да все просто:

- Делаем в C# новое публичное свойство, с тем типом, что мы привязывали к контролу (в нашем случае строка):

  ```
  public string SelectedItem { get; set;}
  ```
- Привязываем соответствующее поле в XAML:

  ```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Lables}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
  ```
- Все, теперь в простом `string` свойстве у нас всегда будет то, что выбрано в UI, без всяких событий, их обработчиков, всяких `sender` и прочей ерунды, сразу нужное значение.

Собственно, трудно было? Не сказал бы, а вот ваш код трудный и неэффективный, так что задумайтесь, правильно вы делаете все или нет. Также из замечаний хочу отметить то, что вы рисуете UI через конструктор, двигая все контролы мышкой, пненебрегая всеми возможными механизмами позиционирования объектов, из-за чего у вас в XAML такое `Margin="333,133,0,0"`, и почти у всего есть статичный размер. Все это приводит к тому, что ваш интерфейс становится "забит гвоздями", ему трудно работать, он не понимает, где и какой объект должен быть, а это в свою очередь сказывается на внешнем виде. Другими словами, ваш UI не будет таким же на другом компьютере, у человека, у которого другое разрешение экрана, другое масштабирование, и так далее, ведь у него не будет `333` помещаться на экране, а значит у него этот объект съедет за пределы окна, либо на другую строку. Поэтому, не используйте конструктор, не используйте такие большие отступы, не используйте размеры (если только они действительно необходимы), ну и не используйте `x:Name` (если только они не для дизайна).

Comment: Спасибо за подробные обьяснения. Можно было и без RadioButton сделать, просто я не понял как событие у Combobox называется,когда выбираешь нужный элемент из списка и он ставится на сам Combobox.Я просто плохо знаю все эти классы и как с ними работать. А времени особо на изучение нет. Нам просто дали 2 курсовых за раз и нам с этим самим разбираться.Поэтому извиняюсь за говнокод)

Comment: @MaximLeo Вы ведь понимаете, что это все оправдания, да? Мне без разницы что у вас там, зачем у вас там, почему у вас там. Тут уже на вашей совести, хотите быть хорошим специалистом - сразу учитесь правильным вещам, невзирая на все трудности, ну а если вам просто нужна корочка - ну чтож, пишите как и раньше и используйте ответ, который дал другой человек, проскочите, а там дальше профессию смените на интересующую вас. Моя лично тут задача сказать как правильно, не более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - круто, какой подробный и поучительный ответ! Спасибо!

Comment: У меня пишет "Не найден контекст данных для привязки Lables".

Comment: @MaximLeo Внимательно еще раз прочитайте ответ, там увидите `DataContext` на конкретный класс, в этом классе **публичное свойство** для привязки, ну и его дальше уже используете.

Answer (score 1):

Простой способ получить первый дочерний элемент определенного типа (например, Lable) заключается в следующем:

```
var label = panel.Children.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Вы либо получаете первый лейбл, либо, если его нет null.

Comment: Вы перепутали с Winforms