# MVVM, WPF: No parameterless constructor defined for type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем здравствуйте, при привязка VM в XAML разметке через DataContext возникла следующая ошибка: No parameterless constructor defined for type ... . Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее исправить

Вот класс VM:

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : RaisePropertyChanged
    {   
        private HandlerDataDictionary handlerData;

        #region text : string - Текст запроса

        /// <summary>Текст запроса</summary>
        public string TextToRequestTB
        {
            get
            {
                return handlerData.TextToRequestTB;
            }
            set
            {
                handlerData.TextToRequestTB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextToRequestTB));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        internal MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            handlerData = new HandlerDataDictionary();

            handlerData.PropertyChanged += OnModelChanged;
        }

        private void OnModelChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
        }
}
```

Вот разметка XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Pr.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.com/icons/"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Pr.ViewModels"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:Pr.Infrastructure.Commands"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Pr"
        Width="700" 
        Height="500"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="Transparent"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>  
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextToRequestTB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="25"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

Comment: `internal MainWindowViewModel()` => `public MainWindowViewModel()`

Comment: `Window.DataContext` [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)