# Как установить случайное ограничение на выбор дня в datagrid с отображением количества лимита в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datepicker

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выставить рандомное число лимита в разные дни. Необходимо, чтобы при выборе даты проверялись другие даты и, при условии, что лимит не превышен, эта дата может быть установлена.

Comment: Вам нужен механизм скажем так "заблокированных дат", у `DatePicker` есть такой, зовется [DatePicker.BlackoutDates](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates), только он не очень дружелюбен к привязкам как по мне, ну и чтоб это обойти, можно попробовать [такой трюк](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686534), это простое расширение, которое позволяет привязать простую коллекцию `ObservableCollection<DateTime>` к этому механизму.

Comment: Ну и вот имея все это вам остается лишь привязать **все** `DatePicker`  к одной коллекции заблокированных дат, а также **все** подписать на событие изменения даты (или прописать в `set` свойства логику), естественно также должна быть одна центральная точка проверки, в этой точке вы уже и проверяете сколько дат уже есть в коллекции плохих, ну и так далее, там уже фантазия ваша.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу пример того, о чем я говорил в комментариях.

#### Подготовительные работы

Возиться с вашим кодом такое себе занятие, пожалуй, создам все с чистого листа, а там уже сами смотрите, надо вам такое или нет.

1. Создаем отдельный класс, в котором будут храниться все свойства для нашего окна, назовем его `MainViewModel` (про MVVM тут речи нет, но советую почитать).
2. Зададим нашему окну `DataContext`, который будет ссылаться на класс, который создали ранее:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new MainViewModel();
   }
   ```

   <sup>По правилам MVVM такой подход плохо, советую почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553).</sup>
3. Далее создаем класс, который будет описывать наш выводимый объект, пусть наше приложение выводит список задач, где каждая задача будет иметь название и дату, когда эту задачу надо выполнить. Значит нам нужен класс одной задачи:

   ```
   public class UserTask
   {
       public UserTask(string name)
           => Name = name;

       public string Name { get; set; } = string. Empty;
       public DateTime Finish { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Теперь мы можем сделать сам список задач. Идем в класс `MainViewModel` и создаем там простую коллекцию нашего класса, заодно и заполним ее:

   ```
   public List<UserTask> Tasks { get; } = new()
   {
       new("Помыть посуду"),
       new("Покормить кота"),
       new("Сходить в душ"),
       new("Заняться спортом"),
       new("Поесть")
   };
   ```

   Обратите внимание, это **публичное свойство**, только к ним возможна привязка, помните это!
5. Имея это, идем в XAML и пишем нужный нам вид, допустим, такой:

   ```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Border
                   Margin="5"
                   Padding="5"
                   BorderBrush="Gray"
                   BorderThickness="1"
                   CornerRadius="5">
                   <Grid>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition />
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                       <TextBlock
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           FontWeight="Medium"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
                       <DatePicker
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Padding="0"
                           Background="Transparent"
                           BorderThickness="0"
                           SelectedDate="{Binding Finish}" />
                   </Grid>
               </Border>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

   С привязками вы знакомы, а значит и смысла объяснять, что и как нет. В двух словах мы просто через `{Binding ...}` указываем публичное свойство из класса, который установлен как `DataContext`.

Все, мы подготовили проект под наши нужды, выглядеть будет так:

[image: Temp Project]

#### Реализуем "плохие даты"

Сейчас наша цель, сделать простую коллекцию `DateTime` типов, при добавлении в которую, все привязанные к ней `DatePicker` должны заблокировать эту дату для выбора.
<sup>За основу взял ответ с [En SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686534/6808809).</sup>

1. За блокировку дат у `DatePicker` отвечает `BlackoutDates`, это простая коллекция объектов `CalendarDateRange`, только вот проблема, мы не можем привязать к ней чего либо, в следствии чего нам нужно сделать некую "обертку", некое "расширение", которое позволит указать нужную нам коллекцию в качестви привязки. Чтож, делаем простой класс и наследуем его от `DependencyObject`, пусть будет называться `DatePickerHelper`.
2. Создаем "Присоединяемое свойство" ([AttachedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/how-to-register-an-attached-property)), написав примерно следующее:

   ```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlackoutDatesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            name: "BlackoutDates",
            propertyType: typeof(ObservableCollection<DateTime>),
            ownerType: typeof(DatePickerHelper),
            defaultMetadata: new (null, OnBindingChanged));

    public static void SetBlackoutDates(DependencyObject d, ObservableCollection<DateTime> value) 
        => d.SetValue(BlackoutDatesProperty, value);

    public static ObservableCollection<DateTime> GetBlackoutDates(DependencyObject d)
        => (ObservableCollection<DateTime>)d.GetValue(BlackoutDatesProperty);

    private static void OnBindingChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // TODO
    }
   ```

   Тут все довольно просто, мы делаем статичные `Get` и `Set` методы, которые нашему свойству будут задавать/забирать значение. Само свойство имеет название, тип (нам нужна коллекция дат, указываем значит ее), а также `typeMetadata` - это некий объект, который позволяет указать значение по умолчанию, а также подписаться на событие изменения привязки, оно нам и нужно. Сам обработчик события пока пустой.
3. Теперь наша цель, это при новой привязке, задавать на основе полученных данных, нужный нам вид для `BlackoutDates`:

   ```
    private static void OnBindingChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (dependencyObject is DatePicker datePicker && eventArgs.NewValue is ObservableCollection<DateTime> blackoutDates)
        {
            datePicker.BlackoutDates.Clear();
            foreach (var date in blackoutDates)
            {
                datePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new(date));
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Тут мы проверяем, нужный нам объект приходит или нет, тем самым получая и коллекцию дат, и `DatePicker`, если все хорошо, то очищаем ранее заданные заблокированные даты, и добавляем новые, из нашей коллекции.
4. Давайте проверим, что получилось, для этого

   - В `MainViewModel` создадим новое свойство наших дат:

     ```
     public ObservableCollection<DateTime> BlackoutDates { get; } = new()
     {
         DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
         DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
     };
     ```
   - В XAML, у `DatePicker` пропишем `local:DatePickerHelper.BlackoutDates="{Binding BlackoutDates}"`.
   - Если все сделали правильно, то должно заблокировать указанные даты в календаре

     [image: Dates Test]
5. У нас сейчас есть один недостаток, при добавлении или удалении дат в коллекцию, наше приложение не будет это обновлять, давайте исправим:

   - В `OnBindingChanged`, после цикла `foreach` подписываемся на событие обновления коллекции, примерно следующим образом:

     ```
     blackoutDates.CollectionChanged += (_, e) => OnCollectionChanged(datePicker, e);
     ```
   - Сам обработчик делаем таким:

     ```
     private static void OnCollectionChanged(DatePicker datePicker, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
     {

     }
     ```

     Думаю заметили, что мы передаем сюда дополнительно еще и `DatePicker`, из-за чего такой "странный" подход к подписыванию на событие.
   - В обработчике теперь прописываем все нужные действия:

     ```
     private static void OnCollectionChanged(DatePicker datePicker, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
     {
         if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add && args.NewItems is not null) 
         {
             foreach (DateTime date in args.NewItems)
             {
                 datePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new(date));
             }
         }
         else if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove && args.OldItems is not null)
         {
             foreach (DateTime date in args.OldItems)
             {
                 var item = datePicker.BlackoutDates.First(x => x.Start == date);
                 datePicker.BlackoutDates.Remove(item);
             }
         }
     }
     ```

     Я тут прописал добавление новых и удаление старых, как и что я думаю уже догадались, просто приводим в нужный вид, а затем при помощи `foreach` делаем нужные манипуляции.

Собственно, вот и все, мы получили удобный проект, где без труда можем заблокировать любую нужную нам дату в любой момент. Остается лишь одно, блокировать их тогда, когда на указанную дату у нас уже есть несколько записей, только это я думаю оставлю уже для вас, а то что я ваше учебное задание делаю за вас) Могу лишь подсказать как сделал бы я:

- Создал бы словарь, который ключом будет иметь дату, а значением число, после которого дата должна блокироваться.
- В класс данных (у нас это `UserTask`) добавил событие, допустим просто `public event Action<DateTime> OnDateUpdate;`.
- При добавлении в коллекцию `Task`, подписался бы на это событие, а чтоб это делалось автоматически, тут можно провернуть аналогичный трюк, как выше с добавлением/удалением новых данных в `ObservableCollection<>`, то есть, по его событию обновления, на новые объекты подписываемся, а от удаленных (старых) наоборот, отписываемся.
- В обработчике события (а он будет один), делаем проверку на наличие ключа в словаре, если есть, то считаем, сколько у нас задач с выбранной датой (`var items = Tasks.Count(x => x.Finish == ...)`), ну и если число равно или больше из словаря, то добавляем дату в коллекцию `BlackoutDates`, если меньше, наоборот удаляем (если есть).
- Ну а так, тут уже полет фантазии, можно сделать по-разному.