# Как забиндить компаненты в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть такой `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DGStudents" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=studends}">
        
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Студент" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Группа" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Group}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Курс" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Course}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Exams}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsEnabled="True">
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.DataContext>
                            <view:OrganaizerManagerVeiwModel/>
                        </Grid.DataContext>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description_of_student}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Классы для биндинга

```
internal class Student: PropertyChanging
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int Course { get; set; }
    public List<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
    public Student(string fullname, string group, int course)
    {
        FullName = fullname;
        Group = group;
        Course = course;
    }
}

internal class Exam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Exam(string name, string decr)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = decr;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

Коллекция, которая забиндена к `DataGrid`

```
 public ObservableCollection<Student> studends { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
            {
                new Student("Ivan Petrov", "21-KB-PR2", 2) 
                    {Exams = new List<Exam>()
                        { 
                        new Exam("Math", "Perfect"),
                        new Exam("OOP", "Good"),
                        new Exam("TRPO", "Bad")
                    }
            }
        };
```

Вопрос. Как можно забиндить два свойства `SelectedItem` и `Description_of_student`
Сами свойства:

```
private Exam _selected_item;

    public Exam SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selected_item;
        set { Set(ref _selected_item, value);
            MessageBox.Show(_selected_item.ToString()); }
    }


    private string description_of_student;

    public string Descruption_of_student
    {
        get => description_of_student;
        set => Set(ref description_of_student, value);
    }
```

При попытке забиндить через `Path` у меня отображаются свойства класса `Student`

Comment: `<Grid.DataContext>` - это что такое и зачем? Если вы меняете `DataContext`, то дальнейшая привязка в нем будет искаться внутри этого класса, что задан как `DataContext`. У вас по сути вообще не должно быть переопределения контекста в XAML, к тому же, это [нарушение MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). +К этому всему, я вам советую подумать над названиями переменных, ибо в C# есть правила именования, которым стоит следовать (прим: `Descruption_of_student` -> `DescruptionOfStudent`).  Ну и последнее, `Path=` лишнее в привязках, достаточно просто `{Binding Exams}`.

Comment: Имена переменных я потом поменяю это тестовый вариант программы, на счет `DataContex`, я в самом начале разметки объявил ко всему окну эту привязку, но мне пришлось еще раз ее использовать по втором `Grid` так как у меня `ComboBox` не видел список `Exams`. Такая же ситуация с `TextBlock`. Возможно я что-то неправильно делаю, если не мложно можете направить или дать хороший пример, который похож на мой\

Comment: Ничего не понял. Как `Exams` связан с установкой `DataContext` у `Grid`, который инициализирует класс `<view:OrganaizerManagerVeiwModel/>`? Я вам даже больше скажу, если вы делаете по правилам MVVM, то это вообще [не правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). Дальше, сами свойства `Description_of_student` и `SelectedItem` где находятся? Рядом с `studends` или внутри класса `Student`? Если первое, то естественно вы так не привяжетесь, ибо если выводите коллекцию, то каждый внутренний объект будет задавать свой источник данных, тут нужен `FindAncestor`.

Comment: Обязательно изучу этот механизм, а на счет `DataContex` у меня есть класс студента, как показано выше, и у него список `Exams` состоящий из класса `Exam`.  Свойства `Description_of_student`  и `SelectedItem` находятся в `VM`, как и сама коллекция `students`. Задача состоит в том, чтобы Прибиндаить к `DataGrid` коллекцию студентов,  далее в `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` объявить отдельный `Grid` и в нем прибиндить имена экзаменов из класса `Exam` к `ComboBox`, а свойство `SelectedItem` собствеено к атрибуту `ComboBox` `SelectedItem`, чтобы я мог отследить какой экзамен выбран и вывести

Comment: `Description_of_student`, который также надо прибиндить к `TextBox`, для каждого экзамена. Ивзиняюсь за столь большой текст

Comment: Ну тогда как и сказал выше, вам нужно найти родителя, ибо когда вы задаете вид элементу из коллекции, то `DataContext` у него будет автоматом объект коллекции, а не предок. `<Grid.DataContext>` убирайте, вам он вообще не нужен здесь, да и вообще забудьте про указание этого в XAML. Ну а `{Binding Path=Description_of_student}` меняете на `{Binding DataContext.Description_of_student, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}`. Условно говоря, мы тут ищем предка в виде `DataGrid`, а у него берем `DataContext` (наша VM), из которой и берем нужное свойство.