# Передача данных из одной viewmodel в другую. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я пишу программу на c#, wpf по паттерну mvvm. Возник вопрос, как передать данные из одной viewmodel в другую. Перерыл кучу похожих статей, но так и не смог разобраться.

У меня есть View, которая содержит информацию о поставках, при нажатии на кнопку появляется UserControl, в котором можно изменять выбранную, на предыдущем UserControl, запись.

```
    //Поле и свойство выбираемой записи
    private SupplyModel _selectedSupply;
    public SupplyModel SelectedSupply
    {
        get => _selectedSupply;
        set
        {
            _selectedSupply = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSupply));

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSupplyWorkers));
        }
    }
    
    //Команда для отображения view для редактирования
    private void ExecuteShowAddSupplyCommand(object? obj)
    {
        CurrentChildView = new EditSupplyViewModel();
        IsEnabled = false;
        BackVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Соответственно вопрос, как я могу передать `SelectedSupply` из `SupplyViewModel` в `EditSupplyViewModel`?
UserControl отображается в ContentControl

```
    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=WidthDockPanel}"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentChildView}">

   <UserControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:EditSupplyViewModel}">
         <local:EditSupplyView/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: ну вы же сами в коде создаете `EditSupplyViewModel` - ну так передайте ему что нужно

Comment: Пробовал. Либо делал, что то не правильно либо так не работает. В `EditSupplyViewModel ` нужно создавать два конструктора, один будет принимать аргументы, а другой нет, так как view ругается, когда во viewmodel нет конструкторов не принимающих значение. И когда происходит инициализация `EditSupplyView`, она создает новый `EditSupplyViewModel `, который уже будет пустой. Вполне вероятно, что я делаю, что то не так и мне нужно передать созданный `EditSupplyViewModel ` в контекст второй view, но я не знаю как.

Comment: view ругается на конструктор только тогда когда вы в дизайнере пытаетесь скормить ему DataContext. для этого есть `d:DataContext...IsDesignTimeCreatable=False`. В рантайме такое будет если **создавать** DataContext прямо во вью - но это "стрелять себе по ногам".

Comment: @vitidev Вау... это действительно сработало, все оказалось намного проще, чем я думал.
Еще маленький вопрос, если не затруднит. Значит, задавать контекст следующим образом плохая идея, верно?
`<UserControl.DataContext>
<viewmodel:SupplyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>`

Comment: Угу. Это и есть "стрелять себе по ногам".  На старте приложения нет проблем создать DataContext и добавить его окну,  а потом и не нужно ибо там уже сплошные DataTemplate. Ну разве что диалоги - но там то же самое, что и для первого окна. Проблема с дизайнером при вьюмоделях без пустых конструкторов? ну да есть. Но мне лучше жесткий контракт, чем добавление пустого конструктора и фейковых данных. Тем более что с d:Prop стало легче жить

Comment: @vitidev Понял, спасибо большое. Жаль комментарий нельзя отменить, как ответ

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553