# Как передать DataContext в DataTemplate на WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:LightComponentViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:ComponentHeader Content="Light" />
    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Type" />
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Type}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataProviderLight}}" Width="150" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Type}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LightComponentsSelector}" />
</StackPanel>
```

У меня в ContentPresenter подставляется нужный DataTemplate через DataTemplateSelector. В зависимости от выбранного значения в Combobox.
Мне нужно в DataTemplate передать текущий `DataContext` "LightComponentViewModel".
Это можно сделать передав в свойство `Content` ContentPresenter'а инстанс LightComponentViewModel.

Но при этом перестает работать смена `DataTemplate` при изменении значения Combobox.

Как можно это исправить ?

Comment: "Как" - Ни как. Вы не должны хотеть этого делать, совсем. 1. `DataContext` в XAML это по сути, [нарушение MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), ибо ваш View вдруг знает и даже более, руководит VM слое. 2. Контролы не должны распыляться на множество разных задач, разных видов и так далее. Вот возьмите к примеру `TextBox`, он знает что либо про данные? Нет. Он лишь что-то делает на основе своего, без вообще каких либо `DataContext`, ну а все данные ему задаются через свойства (`.Text = ...;`). Вот такое должно быть и у вас.

Comment: К примеру (вижу у вас `ContentPresenter`), вы хотите сделать контрол, который будет отвечать за отображение страницы. Создаете его, добавляете свойство зависимости которое принимает простой `object`, ну или интерфейс страницы, его указываете в `ContentPresenter`, снаружи в ресурсы добавляете `DataTemplate`'ы со всеми типами и видами, ну и затем снаружи используете свой контрол как `<ns:SuperControl Page = "{Binging CurrentPage}"/>`, все, ну и как видите, вообще не трогается `DataContext`.